# jQuery table header sort

Tags: jquery, sorting

Anybody know of a plugin, or a built in function to make the columns in a table sortable?  i.e. I click on the column header and it sorts the rows by that column?

Answer (score 27):

http://tablesorter.com/docs/ is very simple to use with a wide range of options to suit your needs. :)

Comment: tablesorter! -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/9535584/665387 has link and example video

Answer (score 3):

http://www.flexigrid.info/

Flexigrid is a very popular, and easy table manager/sorter to use.

Answer (score 2):

Here's two that sort and do many other things as well that I did not yet see listed :

- [DataTables](http://datatables.net/index)
- [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki)

Here is also a table comparing many data tables: http://blog.sematext.com/2011/09/19/top-javascript-dynamic-table-libraries/

Answer (score 1):

A little heavyweight, but the ultimate jQuery table manager is [jqGrid](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqGrid)

Answer (score 0):

A jquery plugin that makes sort, filter and pagination: [breedjs](http://jjppof.github.io/breedjs/)

Example:

Put the data in a js object to do just like so:

```
var data = {
    people: [
        {name: 'a', address: 'c', salesperson: 'b'},
        {name: 'b', address: 'b', salesperson: 'a'},
        {name: 'c', address: 'a', salesperson: 'c'},
    ]
};

breed.run({
    scope: 'people',
    input: data
});
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th sort='name'>Name</th>
            <th sort='address'>Address</th>
            <th sort='salesperson'>Sales Person</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr b-scope="people" b-loop="person in people">
            <td b-sort="name">{{person.name}}</td>
            <td b-sort="address">{{person.address}}</td>
            <td b-sort="salesperson">{{person.salesperson}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now, everytime you want to sort by salesperson, just call it:

```
breed.sort({
    scope: 'people',
    selector: //field name
});
```

See:

```
$("th").click(function(){
    breed.sort({
        scope: 'people',
        selector: $(this).attr('sort')
    });
});
```

[Working example on fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jjppof/madqdjaf/)

Answer (score 0):

### Multiple tables, different data types and no external libraries.

References:

- https://github.com/VFDouglas/HTML-Order-Table-By-Column/blob/main/index.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/72477957/6938902

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column 1 <span>&uarr;</span></th>
                <th>Column 2 <span>&uarr;</span></th>
                <th>Column 3 <span>&uarr;</span></th>
                <th>Column 4 <span>&uarr;</span></th>
                <th>Column 5 <span>&uarr;</span></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>Product 22</td>
                <td>ABCASD</td>
                <td>22DDS</td>
                <td>454645</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>99</td>
                <td>Proddduct 12</td>
                <td>AACASD</td>
                <td>22DDS</td>
                <td>354645</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>300</td>
                <td>Product 22</td>
                <td>AcCASD</td>
                <td>32DDS</td>
                <td>554649</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>400</td>
                <td>Proooooooduct 22</td>
                <td>AcdCASD</td>
                <td>3d2DDS</td>
                <td>554645</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>Product 1</td>
                <td>cCASD</td>
                <td>DDS</td>
                <td>4645</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column 1 <span>&uarr;</span></th>
                <th>Column 2 <span>&uarr;</span></th>
                <th>Column 3 <span>&uarr;</span></th>
                <th>Column 4 <span>&uarr;</span></th>
                <th>Column 5 <span>&uarr;</span></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>Product 221</td>
                <td>ABCASD</td>
                <td>22DDS</td>
                <td>454645</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>99</td>
                <td>Product 12</td>
                <td>AACASD</td>
                <td>22DDS</td>
                <td>354645</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>300</td>
                <td>Product 222</td>
                <td>AcCASD</td>
                <td>32DDS</td>
                <td>554649</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>400</td>
                <td>Product 22</td>
                <td>AcdCASD</td>
                <td>3d2DDS</td>
                <td>554645</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>Product 11</td>
                <td>cCASD</td>
                <td>DDS</td>
                <td>4645</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () { // After page loads
            Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("th")).forEach((element, index) => { // Table headers
                element.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
                    let table = this.closest("table");

                    let order_icon = this.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
                    let order      = encodeURI(order_icon.innerHTML).includes("%E2%86%91") ? "desc" : "asc";

                    let value_list = {}; // <tr> Object
                    let obj_key    = []; // Values of selected column
                    let separator  = "-----"; // Separate the value of it's index, so data keeps intact

                    let string_count = 0;
                    let number_count = 0;

                    table.querySelectorAll("tbody tr").forEach((linha, index_line) => { // <tbody> rows
                        let key = linha.children[element.cellIndex].textContent.toUpperCase();
                        key.replace("-", "").match(/^[0-9,.]*$/g) ? number_count++ : string_count++; // Check if value is numeric or string

                        value_list[key + separator + index_line] = linha.outerHTML.replace(/(\t)|(\n)/g, ''); // Adding <tr> to object
                        obj_key.push(key + separator + index_line);
                    });

                    if (number_count > 0 && string_count <= 0) { // If all values are numeric
                        obj_key.sort(function(a, b) {
                            return a.split(separator)[0] - b.split(separator)[0];
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        obj_key.sort();
                    }

                    if (order == "desc"){
                        obj_key.reverse();
                        order_icon.innerHTML = "&darr;";
                    }
                    else {
                        order_icon.innerHTML = "&uarr;";
                    }

                    let html = "";
                    obj_key.forEach(function (chave) {
                        html += value_list[chave];
                    });
                    table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].innerHTML = html;
                });
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

The [Ext JavaScript library](http://extjs.com/) is very good at that.