# Check whether a value is a number in JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Validate numbers in JavaScript - IsNumeric()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric)

```
var miscCharge = $("#miscCharge").val();
```

I want to check `misCharge` is number or not. Is there any method or easy way in jQuery or JavaScript to do this?

HTMl is

```
<g:textField name="miscCharge"  id ="miscCharge" value="" size="9" max="100000000000" min="0" />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric

Answer (score 196, accepted):

```
function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

Comment: This is even better: `return !isNaN(+n) && isFinite(n)` since for a numeric string with trailing letters the parseFloat | parseInt will return true and the second check isFInite will return false. While with unary `+` it will fail immediately.

Comment: "!isNaN(+n) && isFinite(n)" classifies the empty string as a number

Comment: I'm not sure if this is intended, but isNumber( ['5'] ) would also return true - but it's not a number, it's an array containing a number.

Comment: In one line: +str + '' === str

Answer (score 34):

You've an number of options, depending on how you want to play it:

```
isNaN(val)
```

Returns true if val is not a number, false if it is. In your case, this is probably what you need.

```
isFinite(val)
```

Returns true if val, when cast to a String, is a number and it is not equal to +/- Infinity

```
/^\d+$/.test(val)
```

Returns true if val, when cast to a String, has only digits (probably not what you need).

Comment: vote down because Your regex does not work if `val` is `-1` or `1.5`

Comment: Worth noting that evaluation of an empty string is not what you'd expect: `isNaN('') == false` and `isFinite('') == true`

Comment: @transang Indeed, otherwise using regex is probably the only reliable way if you want to test integers

Answer (score 6):

there is a function called `isNaN` it return true if it's (Not-a-number) , so u can check for a number this way

```
if(!isNaN(miscCharge))
{
   //do some thing if it's a number
}else{
   //do some thing if it's NOT a number
}
```

hope it works

Comment: `isNaN(null)` returns `false`, `isNaN("")` returns `false`

Comment: `isNaN(true)` and `isNaN(false)` also return false