# How to sort a dynamically rendered table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using AJAX to display a table, I need to sort that rendered table at client side using JavaScript or jQuery or whatever is best.

I tried jQuery it is working fine when page is loaded but by dynamically writing html content into a div and there by sorting that rendered table is not working.

I think the problem is JavaScript is not working while rendering, I wrote some script alert while rendering html these tags works while rendering a page.

Comment: Did you try [jQuery tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)?

Comment: What is "not working" supposed to mean? What does your code look like? Can you show us an example that demonstrates the issue, or shall we just guess?

Comment: @salman: Yes i tried jQuery it is working fine for page level rendering but the problem here is jquery sort table or any javascript tags are not getting called while rendering a div...

Comment: Need more code. Are you using `document.write()`s?

Comment: No I am using PHP to send the respond text...
ANd there if i keep any javascript alerts there are not getting execute..:(

Comment: yes, how are you calling the PHP? with the update JS function you are using, setup a callback function

Answer (score 3):

By using tablesorter plugin:

```
$("table").tablesorter();
```

re-running each time table is affected (i.e it will not be enought to run this command once when page loading is complete)

Comment: Why was this answer voted down? If it was due to it containing the same content as Greg's answer, this answer was posted first.

Comment: No idea.. :( I am also upset by the same text copy lower.

Comment: The proper method is to use `$("table").trigger("update");` when updating the table instead of re-running the plugin.

Comment: tablesorter! -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/9535584/665387 has link and example video