# Move table rows with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have this code:

```
<table>
 <tr id="a"><td>A</td></tr>
 <tr id="d"><td>D</td></tr>
 <tr id="e"><td>E</td></tr>
 <tr id="b"><td>B</td></tr>
 <tr id="c"><td>C</td></tr>
</table>
```

How with jQuery can I put the rows in order?

---

**Update:** I need to use a move function not a sort function, since the real id's are not letters. Sorry for the confusion. I want to do something like this:

```
$("#a").after(rows_b_and_c)
```

But I don't know how to get the rows.

Comment: Asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160277/jquery-table-sort

Comment: Nice plug-in, but too much for the problem here. I expect this can be solved with few lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have no events attached to `<td>`s and contents are just text, this will do:

```
var tds = $('table tr').sort(function(a,b){
    return $('td:eq(0)',a).text() > $('td:eq(0)',b).text();
});
$('table').html(tds);
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/7Pb6a/)

---

that depends... how would you order it? please be more specific.

will to give you a hint, you might wanna check out:

[**.after()**](http://api.jquery.com/after/)
Insert content, specified by the parameter, after each element in the set of matched elements.

[**.before()**](http://api.jquery.com/before/)
Insert content, specified by the parameter, before each element in the set of matched elements.

[**.insertAfter()**](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/)
Insert every element in the set of matched elements after the target.

[**.insertBefore()**](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/)
Insert every element in the set of matched elements before the target.

---

you're funny. :p

you said you know those functions then you did not get to solve the problem.

anyway, here are some of the ways to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/7Pb6a/1/

Comment: Smart solution @Reigel, but I used the letters only as example, the real ids are random text and the objective is to move the rows, no to sort them.

Comment: move rows when you click them? sorry if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: I receive the output of an inflexive php code that displays the rows in an incorrect order, I want to re-order them using jQuery.

Comment: I know those functions, but I don't know how to get the rows to put `$("#a").after(rows)`

Comment: Hahaha, You're right @Reigel, I was confused. English is not my language and I didn't understand the difference between after and insertAfter. Somewhere I read that .html() doesn't get the tags of the element, so I couldn't use it to pass data to .after(). Thanks for understand me and have patience! :)

Answer (score 1):

Cleaner:

```
var sortID = function(a,b){
    return a.id > b.id ? 1 : -1;
};
$('table tr').sort(sortID).appendTo('table');
```

Comment: if you're basing on it's id, I bet that won't do much. ;)

Comment: hmmmm... with that latest edit on the question, I have no idea what is being asked ;)