# Issue with table sorting using JavaScript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I'm having an issue when I try to sort my table based on the content in the first column. My code is pretty much the same as the one in this [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10543756/1078428) but in my case, unfortunately, it does not work. As you can see running the snippet the table is not correctly sorted.

```js
$('.sort-table').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();                        // prevent default button click behaviour

    var sortAsc = $(this).hasClass('asc'),     // ASC or DESC
        $table  = $('#sort-table'),            // cache the target table DOM element
        $rows   = $('tbody > tr', $table);     // cache all rows from the target table body

    $rows.sort(function(a, b) {

        var keyA = $('td',a).eq(0).text().trim();
        var keyB = $('td',b).eq(0).text().trim();
        
        if (sortAsc) {
            return (keyA > keyB) ? 1 : 0;     // A bigger than B, sorting ascending
        } else {
            return (keyA < keyB) ? 1 : 0;     // B bigger than A, sorting descending
        }
    });

    $rows.each(function(index, row){
      $table.append(row);                    // append rows after sort
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="sort-table asc">sort ASC</button>
<button class="sort-table desc">sort DESC</button>
<table id="sort-table" border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>MOSELLE CONSTRUCTION ET FAÇADE SA</td>
            <td>xc</td>
            <td>xa</td>
            <td>x&nbsp;Apr&nbsp;x</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td>CHANTIER ECH SUR ALZETTE-STORE A " Z "</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>TECHNIC MONTAGE SARL</td>
            <td>xd</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x&nbsp;Apr&nbsp;x</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td>ANTONIO GEORGE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>MENUIS'ART SARL</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x&nbsp;Apr&nbsp;x</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td>SATRAP DIFF PHASE x - x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>DE OLIVEIRA SANTOS - CWIEK CRISTOVAO ET IWONA</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x&nbsp;May&nbsp;x</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td>idem</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>TECHNIC MONTAGE SARL</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x&nbsp;May&nbsp;x</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td>FERNANDO - RODANGE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>DEMAY SARL</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x&nbsp;Jun&nbsp;x</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td>IDEM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>BETRA SARL</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x&nbsp;Jun&nbsp;x</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td>LOT x RIES-WEISS (KAHLER)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>BER CREATION</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x&nbsp;Jun&nbsp;x</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td>BOUSSE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>MENUIS'ART SARL</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x&nbsp;Jun&nbsp;x</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td>SAV/ULx SEUIL MANQUANT</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>MENUIS'ART SARL</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x&nbsp;Jun&nbsp;x</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td>SAV/NachLieferung GLASLEISTE ELx</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>MURIC &amp; FILS SARL</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x&nbsp;Jun&nbsp;x</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td>x TELECOMMANDES</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>CIALUX SARL</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x&nbsp;Jul&nbsp;x</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td>APP x DOMELDANGE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>MENUIS'ART SARL</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x&nbsp;Jul&nbsp;x</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td>LIMPERSBERG HS - GLAS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>CIALUX SARL</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x&nbsp;Jul&nbsp;x</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td>SAV - BETTANGE-REDING</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>CIALUX SARL</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x&nbsp;Jul&nbsp;x</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td>SAV - DOMMELDANGE - KRAMER</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add another condition to check in your sort

```
    if (sortAsc) {
        // if a > b return 1 / if a < b return -1 / else same so return 0
        return (keyA > keyB) ? 1 : (keyA < keyB) ? -1 : 0;     // A bigger than B, sorting ascending
    } else {
        // if a < b return 1 / if a > b return -1 / else same so return 0
        return (keyA < keyB) ? 1 : (keyA > keyB) ? -1 : 0;     // B bigger than A, sorting descending
    }
```

Also there's no need to loop at the end to append the rows - you can just do

```
$table.find('tbody').append($rows);  // no need to loop through to append
```

```js
$('.sort-table').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();                        // prevent default button click behaviour

    var sortAsc = $(this).hasClass('asc'),     // ASC or DESC
        $table  = $('#sort-table'),            // cache the target table DOM element
        $rows   = $('tbody > tr', $table);     // cache all rows from the target table body

    $rows.sort(function(a, b) {

        var keyA = $('td',a).eq(0).text().trim();
        var keyB = $('td',b).eq(0).text().trim();
        
        if (sortAsc) {
            return (keyA > keyB) ? 1 : (keyA < keyB) ? -1 : 0;     // A bigger than B, sorting ascending
        } else {
            return (keyA < keyB) ? 1 : (keyA > keyB) ? -1 : 0;     // B bigger than A, sorting descending
        }
    });
    $table.find('tbody').append($rows);  // no need to loop through to append  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="sort-table asc">sort ASC</button>
<button class="sort-table desc">sort DESC</button>
<table id="sort-table" border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>MOSELLE CONSTRUCTION ET FAÇADE SA</td>
            <td>xc</td>
            <td>xa</td>
            <td>x&nbsp;Apr&nbsp;x</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td>CHANTIER ECH SUR ALZETTE-STORE A " Z "</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>TECHNIC MONTAGE SARL</td>
            <td>xd</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x&nbsp;Apr&nbsp;x</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td>ANTONIO GEORGE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>MENUIS'ART SARL</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x&nbsp;Apr&nbsp;x</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td>SATRAP DIFF PHASE x - x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>DE OLIVEIRA SANTOS - CWIEK CRISTOVAO ET IWONA</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x&nbsp;May&nbsp;x</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td>idem</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>TECHNIC MONTAGE SARL</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x&nbsp;May&nbsp;x</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td>FERNANDO - RODANGE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>DEMAY SARL</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x&nbsp;Jun&nbsp;x</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td>IDEM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>BETRA SARL</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x&nbsp;Jun&nbsp;x</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td>LOT x RIES-WEISS (KAHLER)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>BER CREATION</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x&nbsp;Jun&nbsp;x</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td>BOUSSE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>MENUIS'ART SARL</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x&nbsp;Jun&nbsp;x</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td>SAV/ULx SEUIL MANQUANT</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>MENUIS'ART SARL</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x&nbsp;Jun&nbsp;x</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td>SAV/NachLieferung GLASLEISTE ELx</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>MURIC &amp; FILS SARL</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x&nbsp;Jun&nbsp;x</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td>x TELECOMMANDES</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>CIALUX SARL</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x&nbsp;Jul&nbsp;x</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td>APP x DOMELDANGE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>MENUIS'ART SARL</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x&nbsp;Jul&nbsp;x</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td>LIMPERSBERG HS - GLAS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>CIALUX SARL</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x&nbsp;Jul&nbsp;x</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td>SAV - BETTANGE-REDING</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>CIALUX SARL</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x&nbsp;Jul&nbsp;x</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td align="right">x.x€</td>
            <td>SAV - DOMMELDANGE - KRAMER</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```