# jQuery sortable contaiment issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, containment

Desired effect: rows (tr) with class do-not-sort excluded from containment using jQuery.sortable.

Current code:
(containment: 'parent'/containment: '.sortable-body')

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Field 1</th>
            <th>Field 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="sortable-body">
        <tr>
            <td>Sortable Field 1</td>
            <td>Sortable Field 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sortable Field 1</td>
            <td>Sortable Field 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="do-not-sort">
            <td colspan="2"><a href="#">Add Row</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I exclude the 'do-not-sort' row at the end (!) of a tbody from the containment? The following didn't work:

> containment: '.sortable-body tr:not(.menu-rij-toevoegen)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You can   identify which items *are* sortable  with the `'items'` parameter -- the value should be specified as a CSS selector.</strike>

So to provide *negative* criteria (exclude elements from the group), use the `:not()` pseudo-class, like this:

```
$('.sortable-body').sortable({ items: 'tr:not(.do-not-sort)' })​;​
```

And it works here, with your precise markup: http://jsfiddle.net/MUEuW/2/

**Update**: probably your best way of excluding the last row from containment is to simply wrap it in a separate `<tbody>` tag.

Multiple `<tbody>`s are legal. See: [Can we have multiple <tbody> in same <table>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076708/can-we-have-multiple-tbody-in-same-table)

Updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/MUEuW/3/

... or do you not have control over the HTML?

Comment: Containment is different from items. In fact, I already specified this items parameter. I'm talking about the 'containment' parameter, as stated in the question.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe <tfoot> is better for this purpose, but the idea is the same.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at my prior post.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9535584/665387

You can specify non sort-able columns like

```
$('#tableRoster').tablesorter({
        headers: {
            0: { sorter: false },
            4: { sorter: false }
        }
    });
```

Comment: jQuery.tablesort is not the same as jQuery.sortable ;)