# jquery sorting for inner html table

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a GridView and getting the data from a database . I have an inner gridview in that gridview as a html table.

I want to know how to do jquery sorting for the inner html table in gridview.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160277/jquery-table-sort

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. [tablesorter jQuery plugin](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)

   tablesorter is a jQuery plugin for turning a standard HTML table with THEAD and TBODY tags into a sortable table without page refreshes. tablesorter can successfully parse and sort many types of data including linked data in a cell. It has many useful features including:

   Multi-column sorting
   Parsers for sorting text, URIs, integers, currency, floats, IP addresses, dates (ISO, long and short formats), time. Add your own easily
   Support secondary "hidden" sorting (e.g., maintain alphabetical sort when sorting on other criteria)
   Extensibility via widget system
   Cross-browser: IE 6.0+, FF 2+, Safari 2.0+, Opera 9.0+
   Small code size