# jQuery tablesorter issue - sorting with rowspan

Tags: jquery, html-table, tablesorter

I'm using [jQuery tablesorter](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) on my table. Without `rowspan`, the table sorts fine, but when I add `rowspan`, the sorting destroys my table layout.

#### Here's some sample code:

```html
<table cellspacing="1" class="tablesorter">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Peter</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td rowspan="2" style="vertical-align:middle">AAA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>33</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Clark</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>BBB</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Bruce</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>CCC</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
$(".tablesorter").tablesorter({});
```

Without clicking sort, my table looks like this:

[image: Without Sorting]

When I click on country header, the table gets really garbledL

[image: With Sorting]

Comment: I don't think tablesorter supports sorting with rowspans. There's [an open issue about it](https://github.com/christianbach/tablesorter/issues/111) assuming this is the tablesorter you're talking about.

Comment: if it is not support, is there any alternative way to do sort with rowspan

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12898951/jquery-sortcolumns-plugin-how-to-sort-correctly-with-rowspan may help

Comment: Just to clarify two points.  1.  Pretending we change "Peter" to "Alan", and we sort on first name, do you want the results to split those first two lines?  ie. answer is "Alan-28-AAA", "Bruce-22-CCC", "Clark-18-BBB", "John-33-AAA" (so no rowspans on country)?  2.  Are you always collapsing on adjacent countries equal (regardless of sort field), or on the sorted field (eg sorting on age would create age rowspans)?

Answer (score 8):

One "simple" solution would be to make all rows that are included in the `rowspan` a child row:

- Original tablesorter ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eY8uH/1731/))

  ```
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>28</td>
    <td rowspan="2" style="vertical-align:middle">AAA</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="expand-child">
    <td>John</td>
    <td>33</td>
  </tr>
  ```

  Initialize JS

  ```
  $(function() {
    $('table').tablesorter();
  });
  ```
- Tablesorter fork ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bbxxomhx/108/)) - class name was changed in the fork

  ```
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>28</td>
    <td rowspan="2" style="vertical-align:middle">AAA</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tablesorter-childRow">
    <td>John</td>
    <td>33</td>
  </tr>
  ```

  Initialize JS

  ```
  $(function() {
    $('table').tablesorter({
      theme: 'blue'
    });
  });
  ```

Because of the rowspan being set as child rows, they won't be included in the sort nor will they switch places with the parent.

Comment: HI @Mottie, I don't see any sorting using your method.

Comment: Hi Dejan, try setting the `debug` option to troubleshoot. If that doesn't help, please ask a new question with your code in a demo.