# Sorting HTML table with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sorting, html-table

I'm after a table sorting solution (in JavaScript) but I can't seem to find a suitable one yet. I just need it to sort each column alphabetically. It doesn't need to ignore any code or any numbers or to work with currency. Just a click on the column header switches it from sorted a-z/z-a.

Does anyone know of a really simple solution like this?

Answer (score 281, accepted):

Just revisiting [an old solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160277/jquery-table-sort/19947532#19947532), I thought I'd give it a facelift for it's ~5 year anniversary!

- Plain Javascript (ES6)
- Does alpha and numeric sorting - ascending and descending
- Works in **Chrome**, **Firefox**, **Safari** (and **IE11**, see below)

#### Quick explanation

1. add a `click` event to all header (`th`) cells...
2. for the current `table`, find all rows (except the first)...
3. sort the rows, based on the value of the clicked column...
4. insert the rows back into the table, in the new order.

```js
const getCellValue = (tr, idx) => tr.children[idx].innerText || tr.children[idx].textContent;

const comparer = (idx, asc) => (a, b) => ((v1, v2) => 
    v1 !== '' && v2 !== '' && !isNaN(v1) && !isNaN(v2) ? v1 - v2 : v1.toString().localeCompare(v2)
    )(getCellValue(asc ? a : b, idx), getCellValue(asc ? b : a, idx));

// do the work...
document.querySelectorAll('th').forEach(th => th.addEventListener('click', (() => {
    const table = th.closest('table');
    Array.from(table.querySelectorAll('tr:nth-child(n+2)'))
        .sort(comparer(Array.from(th.parentNode.children).indexOf(th), this.asc = !this.asc))
        .forEach(tr => table.appendChild(tr) );
})));
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
th {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr><th>Country</th><th>Date</th><th>Size</th></tr>
    <tr><td>France</td><td>2001-01-01</td><td><i>25</i></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href=#>spain</a></td><td><i>2005-05-05</i></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>Lebanon</b></td><td><a href=#>2002-02-02</a></td><td><b>-17</b></td></tr>
    <tr><td><i>Argentina</i></td><td>2005-04-04</td><td><a href=#>100</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>USA</td><td></td><td>-6</td></tr>
</table>
```

---

### IE11 Support (non-ES6)

If you want to support IE11, you'll need to ditch the ES6 syntax and use alternatives to [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Polyfill) and [`Element.closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest#Polyfill).

#### i.e.

```
var getCellValue = function(tr, idx){ return tr.children[idx].innerText || tr.children[idx].textContent; }

var comparer = function(idx, asc) { return function(a, b) { return function(v1, v2) {
        return v1 !== '' && v2 !== '' && !isNaN(v1) && !isNaN(v2) ? v1 - v2 : v1.toString().localeCompare(v2);
    }(getCellValue(asc ? a : b, idx), getCellValue(asc ? b : a, idx));
}};

// do the work...
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('th')).forEach(function(th) { th.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var table = th.parentNode
        while(table.tagName.toUpperCase() != 'TABLE') table = table.parentNode;
        Array.prototype.slice.call(table.querySelectorAll('tr:nth-child(n+2)'))
            .sort(comparer(Array.prototype.slice.call(th.parentNode.children).indexOf(th), this.asc = !this.asc))
            .forEach(function(tr) { table.appendChild(tr) });
    })
});
```

#### Comparer function breakdown

For the sake of brevity, I compacted the `comparer()` function. It's a little complex/hard to read, so here it is again exploded/formatted/commented.

```js
// Returns a function responsible for sorting a specific column index 
// (idx = columnIndex, asc = ascending order?).
var comparer = function(idx, asc) { 

    // This is used by the array.sort() function...
    return function(a, b) { 

        // This is a transient function, that is called straight away. 
        // It allows passing in different order of args, based on 
        // the ascending/descending order.
        return function(v1, v2) {

            // sort based on a numeric or localeCompare, based on type...
            return (v1 !== '' && v2 !== '' && !isNaN(v1) && !isNaN(v2)) 
                ? v1 - v2 
                : v1.toString().localeCompare(v2);
        }(getCellValue(asc ? a : b, idx), getCellValue(asc ? b : a, idx));
    }
};
```

Comment: Note that the statement th.parentNode.parentNode fails if the header row is wrapped in a <thead> element. I'd suggest using "var table = th.closest('table');". Note that Element.closest() doesn't seem to be implemented in IE11/Edge.

Comment: A comment for newbies in javascript like me, because I've lost a lot of time to understand why it doesn't work for me. So, if you just put this script in your html in <script> tag, nothing happens. You need to link this function to some event, for example to load window: window.onload=function(){ /*script from this answer */} and then it works fine!

Comment: @NickGrealy Thanks for graceful code! What is this designation called: `this.asc = !this.asc`

Comment: @dsb ... not sure... "variable inversion"? :)

Comment: @NickGrealy cool method to toggle a boolean! Just want to reach your high level of programming

Comment: Is there a solution that handles prefixes like $ or other currencies?

Comment: @KyleUnderhill - simply strip all the currency characters (`$` ,etc) before doing the compare -> and the currencies will be treated as numbers. As for the `,` delimiter, it means different things in different locales (i.e. "thousand" separator (Australia) vs "decimal" separator (Europe)). I'll leave that solution to you.

Comment: Excellent! By the way, `Array.from(th.parentNode.children).indexOf(th)` might be written `this.cellIndex` (`cellIndex` is well supported by browsers [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableCellElement#Browser_compatibility] )

Comment: @KyleUnderhill - I had to work with file sizes KB, MB, GB, etc., so I used `myTD.textContent` to display the formatted sizes and internally `myTD.dataset.v` in order to sort the sizes - this means also to update `getCellValue` by inserting `=> tr.children[idx].dataset.v ||` at the very beginning of the code.

Comment: If your rows are inside a `<tbody>` tag and this answer acts up, see [this tweak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53880407/736937) to this answer.

Comment: Hey all. I used that code (code for IE) to sort my table and it worked fine except if we have numbers in the string of the <td> value. For example "hallo 25.Months" and "hallo 7.Months". 
The sorter will sort the 25 before the 7. Even if I tell the comparer that he should be {numeric: true}. Someone has an idea?

Comment: @albert - see my response to KyleUnderhill (re: stripping non-numeric characters).

Comment: Remove comment, add code inside `javascript:(function(){ ...  })();` and you get nice bookmarklet

Comment: any ideas how to make this work so that a final summary row doesn't get sorted?

Comment: This worked great for dates when I was using the `2020-03-17` date format, but now my client wants the dates to appear like `17-Mar-20`. Date sorter no longer works. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: @kbdev - there is a solution! - add your own custom date detection, parsing and sorting logic to the `comparer` function (very easy to do).

Comment: I'm getting the error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'asc' of undefined at HTMLTableCellElement.<anonymous>", any idea why?

Comment: Ah, it was because I was jusing <script type="module">, weird.  So the `this` in `this.asc` is just referencing the window?  That seems odd to me because if you sort one column then sort the other, the other will be sorted descending instead of ascending? Shouldn't that be stored with each <th>?

Comment: Could the same functionality also be applied to when you click a button that exists within the Table Header row? For example, fi there is a glyphicon which you would prefer to click rather than the general table header row.

Comment: @Stephen85 - Absolutely you could do that. Wouldn't take much extra code to support it.

Comment: The `comparer` function is _extremely_ difficult to read. I have spent hours trying to make sense of it. Can you please explain what the hell is going on there? It's giving me a headache. This is a request from someone with years in JavaScript development. I understand that we're dealing with closures here, but that doesn't help much.

Comment: @Pyromonk yes, could be better explained. I've updated the solution. If you still need help, please reach out.

Comment: @NickGrealy, thank you, I had figured it out eventually (after 6 hours or so), and your expanded answer definitely helped! I'm still wondering how one actually writes a function like that... I don't think I could use such a trick for passing parameters even after understanding it. It seems kind of counterintuitive (but very helpful in certain scenarios at the same time).

Comment: Thank you! I have my table in a popup, which can be opened/closed multiple times, so had to change ```const``` for ```var```, as cannot redeclare ```const's```

Comment: Trouble sorting numbers with affixes (e.g. `$1`, `0.5%`)? Instead of stripping them on the fly, add the raw value as a cell data-attribute, e.g. ```data-value="0.5"```, and then update the ```getCellValue``` function with ```tr.children[idx].dataset['value'] || tr.children[idx].innerText``` to look for the raw data before using innerText. Should perform better on larger datasets.

Comment: Very nice! I had to check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild to get why table.appendChild(tr) does not double the current tr. MDN  states: " If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the document, appendChild() moves it from its current position to the new position".

Comment: This is working almost, I have to double click for it to work...

Comment: Works like a charm with the [tbody patch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53880407) from jedwards. Thanks!

Comment: There seems to be a little flaw though: When I click sort on one column, it is sorted ascending. When I next click on another column, it is sorted descending. I tried to fix that myself by adding an `asc` , so that a click on a different column resets the`asc` value

Answer (score 87):

I wrote up some code that will sort a table by a row, assuming only one `<tbody>` and cells don't have a *colspan*.

```
function sortTable(table, col, reverse) {
    var tb = table.tBodies[0], // use `<tbody>` to ignore `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` rows
        tr = Array.prototype.slice.call(tb.rows, 0), // put rows into array
        i;
    reverse = -((+reverse) || -1);
    tr = tr.sort(function (a, b) { // sort rows
        return reverse // `-1 *` if want opposite order
            * (a.cells[col].textContent.trim() // using `.textContent.trim()` for test
                .localeCompare(b.cells[col].textContent.trim())
               );
    });
    for(i = 0; i < tr.length; ++i) tb.appendChild(tr[i]); // append each row in order
}
// sortTable(tableNode, columId, false);
```

If you don't want to make the assumptions above, you'd need to consider how you want to behave in each circumstance. (e.g. put everything into one `<tbody>` or add up all the preceeding *colspan* values, etc.)

You could then attach this to each of your tables, e.g. assuming titles are in `<thead>`

```
function makeSortable(table) {
    var th = table.tHead, i;
    th && (th = th.rows[0]) && (th = th.cells);
    if (th) i = th.length;
    else return; // if no `<thead>` then do nothing
    while (--i >= 0) (function (i) {
        var dir = 1;
        th[i].addEventListener('click', function () {sortTable(table, i, (dir = 1 - dir))});
    }(i));
}

function makeAllSortable(parent) {
    parent = parent || document.body;
    var t = parent.getElementsByTagName('table'), i = t.length;
    while (--i >= 0) makeSortable(t[i]);
}
```

and then invoking `makeAllSortable` *onload*.

---

Example [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zscQy/) of it working on a table.

Comment: Ah, my mistake with the hiding table. Just trying this out now. Just to clarify, I'd be adding the `makeAllSortable()` to the body onload correct?

Comment: Yep, re-copy the code as it stands now though because I edited it. Also ensure you understand the assumptions I made.

Comment: @lucas572 it currently only makes a decision based upon `.textContent.trim()` (which doesn't change based on checkbox state, etc). If you want to to decide in other ways, teach it how in `.sort`.

Comment: @PaulS. thank you very much, very useful. I tested it on all browsers, and it worked just fine, except for IE10, do you have any idea why?

Comment: @user2517028 using _IE11_ to emulate older versions, it works for me until IE8 where `addEventListener` fails (and `String.prototype.trim` would fail too). To try and find out what went wrong, press F12 and take a look at what errors appear/ed in the _Console_.

Comment: Thanks, nice code. Any idea how to make it works with numbers? Because actually 9 is considered bigger than 42 for example. I'd like to avoid to pad the numbers if possible...

Comment: Also, why do you need to trim() the strings?

Comment: @Fla trim because whitespace can change expected behaviour. If you want string-or-number etc, google natural sort

Comment: Answer to myself, I find in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#Using_options) the usage of options, so use the `numeric: true` one and you'll be good with numbers, even inside strings. Replace `.localeCompare(b.cells[col].textContent.trim())` by `.localeCompare(b.cells[col].textContent.trim(), undefined, {numeric: true})`

Comment: @PaulS. Hi, I have a question about sorting number. There are positive and negative numbers in my table and this script this script wrongly sorts negative numbers from positive Look at this example: jsfiddle.net/zscQy/775

Answer (score 71):

[Nick Grealy's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49041392/736937) is great but acts a bit quirky if your rows are inside a `<tbody>` tag (the first row isn't ever sorted and after sorting rows end up outside of the tbody tag, possibly losing formatting).

This is a simple fix, however:

Just change:

```
document.querySelectorAll('th').forEach(th => th.addEventListener('click', (() => {
  const table = th.closest('table');
  Array.from(table.querySelectorAll('tr:nth-child(n+2)'))
    .sort(comparer(Array.from(th.parentNode.children).indexOf(th), this.asc = !this.asc))
    .forEach(tr => table.appendChild(tr) );
```

to:

```
document.querySelectorAll('th').forEach(th => th.addEventListener('click', (() => {
  const table = th.closest('table');
  const tbody = table.querySelector('tbody');
  Array.from(tbody.querySelectorAll('tr'))
    .sort(comparer(Array.from(th.parentNode.children).indexOf(th), this.asc = !this.asc))
    .forEach(tr => tbody.appendChild(tr) );
```

Comment: Excellent fix! I was having issues because my table had `<tbody>` and this fixed it right up

Comment: You've absolutely saved me! I was trying to fix the same thing without any luck. This is very clean solution to tbody tag / fixed first row issue.

Comment: If I've used formatters in to_html, my float numbers has been converted to string, which makes above sorting function not working correctly. Is it possible to upgrade the code so its converts string resulting from lambda x: '{0:.3f}%'.format(x*100)  back to float just to sort it correctly?

Comment: I can fix string formatting of the float by using parseFloat in this case I've amended 1 of your lines: (parseFloat(getCellValue(asc ? a : b, idx)), parseFloat(getCellValue(asc ? b : a, idx)). The problem is that for non-float_as_string columns parseFloat will return NaN which won't allow for sorting. I am struggling to fix your code so it can check isNaN for parseFloat before parseing.

Comment: This works for all fields except my date field.  Any ideas why it would not work with a date field?

Answer (score 8):

The best way I know to sort HTML table with javascript is with the following function.

Just pass to it the id of the table you'd like to sort and the column number on the row. it assumes that the column you are sorting is numeric or has numbers in it and will do regex replace to get the number itself (great for currencies and other numbers with symbols in it).

```
function sortTable(table_id, sortColumn){
    var tableData = document.getElementById(table_id).getElementsByTagName('tbody').item(0);
    var rowData = tableData.getElementsByTagName('tr');            
    for(var i = 0; i < rowData.length - 1; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < rowData.length - (i + 1); j++){
            if(Number(rowData.item(j).getElementsByTagName('td').item(sortColumn).innerHTML.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, "")) < Number(rowData.item(j+1).getElementsByTagName('td').item(sortColumn).innerHTML.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ""))){
                tableData.insertBefore(rowData.item(j+1),rowData.item(j));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using example:

```
$(function(){
    // pass the id and the <td> place you want to sort by (td counts from 0)
    sortTable('table_id', 3);
});
```

Comment: I like this solution, but isn't it faster to use the sort() ?

Comment: Why do you need to place an anonymous function in a jQuery thing just to call your function? Couldn't you simply call `sortTable('table_id', 3)` directly?

Answer (score 8):

Table Sorting with :hover arrows effect. Simply add the class `.order` to the `<th>` element of each column to be ordered

```js
function table_sort() {
  const styleSheet = document.createElement('style')
  styleSheet.innerHTML = `
        .order-inactive span {
            visibility:hidden;
        }
        .order-inactive:hover span {
            visibility:visible;
        }
        .order-active span {
            visibility: visible;
        }
    `
  document.head.appendChild(styleSheet)

  document.querySelectorAll('th.order').forEach(th_elem => {
    let asc = true
    const span_elem = document.createElement('span')
    span_elem.style = "font-size:0.8rem; margin-left:0.5rem"
    span_elem.innerHTML = "▼"
    th_elem.appendChild(span_elem)
    th_elem.classList.add('order-inactive')

    const index = Array.from(th_elem.parentNode.children).indexOf(th_elem)
    th_elem.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      document.querySelectorAll('th.order').forEach(elem => {
        elem.classList.remove('order-active')
        elem.classList.add('order-inactive')
      })
      th_elem.classList.remove('order-inactive')
      th_elem.classList.add('order-active')

      if (!asc) {
        th_elem.querySelector('span').innerHTML = '▲'
      } else {
        th_elem.querySelector('span').innerHTML = '▼'
      }
      const arr = Array.from(th_elem.closest("table").querySelectorAll('tbody tr'))
      arr.sort((a, b) => {
        const a_val = a.children[index].innerText
        const b_val = b.children[index].innerText
        return (asc) ? a_val.localeCompare(b_val) : b_val.localeCompare(a_val)
      })
      arr.forEach(elem => {
        th_elem.closest("table").querySelector("tbody").appendChild(elem)
      })
      asc = !asc
    })
  })
}

table_sort()
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="order">Country</th>
      <th class="order">Date</th>
      <th class="order">Size</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>France</td>
      <td>2001-01-01</td>
      <td><i>25</i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href=#>spain</a></td>
      <td><i>2005-05-05</i></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Lebanon</b></td>
      <td><a href=#>2002-02-02</a></td>
      <td><b>-17</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><i>Argentina</i></td>
      <td>2005-04-04</td>
      <td><a href=#>100</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>USA</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>-6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Worked great after fixing the heading being sorted. Used: `const arr = Array.from(th_elem.closest("table").querySelectorAll('tbody tr')).slice(1)`

Comment: Querying `closest` table and its tbody in a loop is inefficient. You should cache `tbody` to a variable. Also you can replace `appendChild`in a loop with single call of `replaceChildren`: `tbody.replaceChildren(...arr)`.

Answer (score 7):

It does WAY more than "just sorting", but dataTables.net does what you need. I use it daily and is well supported and VERY fast (does require jQuery)

http://datatables.net/

> DataTables is a plug-in for the jQuery Javascript library. It is a highly flexible tool, based upon the foundations of progressive enhancement, which will add advanced interaction controls to any HTML table.

Google Visualizations is another option, but requires a bit more setup that dataTables, but does NOT require any particular framework/library (other than google.visualizations):

http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#table

And there are other options to... especially if you're using one of the other JS frameworks. Dojo, Prototype, etc all have usable "table enhancement" plugins that provide at minimum table sorting functionality. Many provide more, but I'll restate...I've yet to come across one as powerful and as FAST as datatables.net.

Comment: hmm I'll take a look at that. Was hoping for a javascript solution though, but hey if this works!

My only worry with some is that they get confused when there's HTML in the table, will this just read through the HTML and not really care what it's looking at? Or will it try to ignore it?

Comment: Well, technically it is JavaScript. jQuery is nothing but a JS framework...not magic. DataTables is pretty good about dealing with some HTML, however, you may need to write a custom sorter (documented on his website)

Comment: @BLSully : what about http://listjs.com/ ? I read that datatables was quite chunky, a big canon for shooting small birds in some cases

Comment: @AdrienBe: Nice suggestion! Haven't run across that one before. Will have to see how it does with really large data sets. I've run 15,000+ rows in DataTables before and it's performance remains acceptable in modern browsers. But I will definitely agree that DataTables can be too large of a hammer for some problems. ListJS looks like a great alternative (and also lets you use html other than tables)

Comment: @BLSully: been using it today and it seems alright, here is a very simple example to get you started http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20528593/using-list-js-sort-and-search-not-working/23078200#23078200

Answer (score 4):

You could deal with a json array and the `sort` function. It is a pretty easy maintanable structure to manipulate (ex: sorting).

Untested, but here's the idea. That would support multiple ordering and sequential ordering if you pass in a array in which you put the columns in the order they should be ordered by.

```
var DATA_TABLE = {
    {name: 'George', lastname: 'Blarr', age:45},
    {name: 'Bob', lastname: 'Arr', age: 20}
    //...
};

function sortDataTable(arrayColNames, asc) { // if not asc, desc
    for (var i=0;i<arrayColNames.length;i++) {
        var columnName = arrayColNames[i];
        DATA_TABLE = DATA_TABLE.sort(function(a,b){
            if (asc) {
                return (a[columnName] > b[columnName]) ? 1 : -1;
            } else {
                return (a[columnName] < b[columnName]) ? 1 : -1;
            }
        });
    }
}

function updateHTMLTable() {
    // update innerHTML / textContent according to DATA_TABLE
    // Note: textContent for firefox, innerHTML for others
}
```

Now let's imagine you need to order by lastname, then name, and finally by age.

```
var orderAsc = true;
sortDataTable(['lastname', 'name', 'age'], orderAsc);
```

It should result in something like :

```
{name: 'Jack', lastname: 'Ahrl', age: 20},
{name: 'Jack', lastname: 'Ahrl', age: 22},
//...
```

Comment: I have a fairly long table of ~200 rows and growing. Do you think this method would be faster than the other answers?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a complete example using pure JavaScript. The algorithm used for sorting is basically [BubbleSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m1rzupv0/).

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function sort(ascending, columnClassName, tableId) {
        var tbody = document.getElementById(tableId).getElementsByTagName(
                "tbody")[0];
        var rows = tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr");

        var unsorted = true;

        while (unsorted) {
            unsorted = false

            for (var r = 0; r < rows.length - 1; r++) {
                var row = rows[r];
                var nextRow = rows[r + 1];

                var value = row.getElementsByClassName(columnClassName)[0].innerHTML;
                var nextValue = nextRow.getElementsByClassName(columnClassName)[0].innerHTML;

                value = value.replace(',', '.'); // in case a comma is used in float number
                nextValue = nextValue.replace(',', '.');

                if (!isNaN(value)) {
                    value = parseFloat(value);
                    nextValue = parseFloat(nextValue);
                }

                if (ascending ? value > nextValue : value < nextValue) {
                    tbody.insertBefore(nextRow, row);
                    unsorted = true;
                }
            }
        }
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="content-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="id">ID <a
                    href="javascript:sort(true, 'id', 'content-table');">asc</a> <a
                    href="javascript:sort(false, 'id', 'content-table');">des</a>
                </th>
                <th class="country">Country <a
                    href="javascript:sort(true, 'country', 'content-table');">asc</a> <a
                    href="javascript:sort(false, 'country', 'content-table');">des</a>
                </th>
                <th class="some-fact">Some fact <a
                    href="javascript:sort(true, 'some-fact', 'content-table');">asc</a>
                    <a href="javascript:sort(false, 'some-fact', 'content-table');">des</a>
                <th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="id">001</td>
                <td class="country">Germany</td>
                <td class="some-fact">16.405</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="id">002</td>
                <td class="country">France</td>
                <td class="some-fact">10.625</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="id">003</td>
                <td class="country">UK</td>
                <td class="some-fact">15.04</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="id">004</td>
                <td class="country">China</td>
                <td class="some-fact">13.536</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

You can also check out the source from here: https://github.com/wmentzel/table-sort

Answer (score 3):

Sorting table rows by cell.
 1. Little simpler and has some features.
 2. Distinguish 'number' and 'string' on sorting
 3. Add toggle to sort by ASC, DESC

```
var index;      // cell index
var toggleBool; // sorting asc, desc 
function sorting(tbody, index){
    this.index = index;
    if(toggleBool){
        toggleBool = false;
    }else{
        toggleBool = true;
    }

    var datas= new Array();
    var tbodyLength = tbody.rows.length;
    for(var i=0; i<tbodyLength; i++){
        datas[i] = tbody.rows[i];
    }

    // sort by cell[index] 
    datas.sort(compareCells);
    for(var i=0; i<tbody.rows.length; i++){
        // rearrange table rows by sorted rows
        tbody.appendChild(datas[i]);
    }   
}

function compareCells(a,b) {
    var aVal = a.cells[index].innerText;
    var bVal = b.cells[index].innerText;

    aVal = aVal.replace(/\,/g, '');
    bVal = bVal.replace(/\,/g, '');

    if(toggleBool){
        var temp = aVal;
        aVal = bVal;
        bVal = temp;
    } 

    if(aVal.match(/^[0-9]+$/) && bVal.match(/^[0-9]+$/)){
        return parseFloat(aVal) - parseFloat(bVal);
    }
    else{
          if (aVal < bVal){
              return -1; 
          }else if (aVal > bVal){
                return 1; 
          }else{
              return 0;       
          }         
    }
}
```

below is html sample

```
            <table summary="Pioneer">

                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col"  onclick="sorting(tbody01, 0)">No.</th>
                        <th scope="col"  onclick="sorting(tbody01, 1)">Name</th>
                        <th scope="col"  onclick="sorting(tbody01, 2)">Belong</th>
                        <th scope="col"  onclick="sorting(tbody01, 3)">Current Networth</th>
                        <th scope="col"  onclick="sorting(tbody01, 4)">BirthDay</th>
                        <th scope="col"  onclick="sorting(tbody01, 5)">Just Number</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody id="tbody01">
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>Gwanshic Yi</td>
                        <td>Gwanshic Home</td>
                        <td>120000</td>
                        <td>1982-03-20</td>
                        <td>124,124,523</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>Steve Jobs</td>
                        <td>Apple</td>
                        <td>19000000000</td>
                        <td>1955-02-24</td>
                        <td>194,523</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>Bill Gates</td>
                        <td>MicroSoft</td>
                        <td>84300000000</td>
                        <td>1955-10-28</td>
                        <td>1,524,124,523</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>Larry Page</td>
                        <td>Google</td>
                        <td>39100000000</td>
                        <td>1973-03-26</td>
                        <td>11,124,523</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another compact but readable solution:
It just requires adding the class `.order` to the `<th>` element of each column to be ordered

```
document.querySelectorAll('th.order').forEach(th_elem => {
    let asc=true
    const index = Array.from(th_elem.parentNode.children).indexOf(th_elem)          
    th_elem.addEventListener('click', (e) => {              
        const arr = [... th_elem.closest("table").querySelectorAll('tbody tr')]
        arr.sort( (a, b) => {
            const a_val = a.children[index].innerText
            const b_val = b.children[index].innerText                   
            return (asc) ? a_val.localeCompare(b_val) : b_val.localeCompare(a_val)
        })
        arr.forEach(elem => {                   
            th_elem.closest("table").querySelector("tbody").appendChild(elem)
        })
        asc = !asc
    })
})
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this beautiful solution!
I just had to slice off the first line of the table to prevent the TH from being sorted...

const arr = [... th_elem.closest("table").querySelectorAll('tbody tr')].slice(1)

Answer (score 1):

In case your table does not have `th`s but only `td`s (with headers included) you can try the following which is based on Nick Grealy's answer above:

```js
const getCellValue = (tr, idx) => tr.children[idx].innerText || tr.children[idx].textContent;

const comparer = (idx, asc) => (a, b) => ((v1, v2) => 
    v1 !== '' && v2 !== '' && !isNaN(v1) && !isNaN(v2) ? v1 - v2 : v1.toString().localeCompare(v2)
    )(getCellValue(asc ? a : b, idx), getCellValue(asc ? b : a, idx));

// do the work...
document.querySelectorAll('tr:first-child td').forEach(td => td.addEventListener('click', (() => {
    const table = td.closest('table');
    Array.from(table.querySelectorAll('tr:nth-child(n+2)'))
        .sort(comparer(Array.from(td.parentNode.children).indexOf(td), this.asc = !this.asc))
        .forEach(tr => table.appendChild(tr) );
})));
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');

*{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-transform:capitalize;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align:left;
}

table {
 color:#666;
 font-size:12px;
 background:#124;
 border:#ccc 1px solid;
 -moz-border-radius:3px;
 -webkit-border-radius:3px;
 border-radius:3px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

table td {
 padding:10px;
 border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
 border-bottom:1px solid #e0e0e0;
 border-left: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
 background: #fafafa;
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fbfbfb), to(#fafafa));
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #fbfbfb,  #fafafa);
  width: 6.9in;
}

table tbody tr:first-child td
{
 background: #124!important;
  color:#fff;
}

table tbody tr th
{
  padding:10px;
  border-left: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
 background: #124!important;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<table>
        <tr><td>Country</td><td>Date</td><td>Size</td></tr>
        <tr><td>France</td><td>2001-01-01</td><td><i>25</i></td></tr>
        <tr><td>spain</td><td>2005-05-05</td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Lebanon</td><td>2002-02-02</td><td><b>-17</b></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Argentina</td><td>2005-04-04</td><td>100</td></tr>
        <tr><td>USA</td><td></td><td>-6</td></tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to sort HTML table. (based on **[W3.JS HTML Sort](https://www.w3schools.com/w3js/w3js_sort.asp)**)

```js
var collection = [{
  "Country": "France",
  "Date": "2001-01-01",
  "Size": "25",
}, {
  "Country": "spain",
  "Date": "2005-05-05",
  "Size": "",
}, {
  "Country": "Lebanon",
  "Date": "2002-02-02",
  "Size": "-17",
}, {
  "Country": "Argentina",
  "Date": "2005-04-04",
  "Size": "100",
}, {
  "Country": "USA",
  "Date": "",
  "Size": "-6",
}]

for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  $("#myTable th:eq(" + j + ")").addClass("control-label clickable");
  $("#myTable th:eq(" + j + ")").attr('onClick', "w3.sortHTML('#myTable', '.item', 'td:nth-child(" + (j + 1) + ")')");
}

$tbody = $("#myTable").append('<tbody></tbody>');

for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
  $tbody = $tbody.append('<tr class="item"><td>' + collection[i]["Country"] + '</td><td>' + collection[i]["Date"] + '</td><td>' + collection[i]["Size"] + '</td></tr>');
}
```

```css
.control-label:after {
  content: "*";
  color: red;
}

.clickable {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.js"></script>
<link href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<p>Click the <strong>table headers</strong> to sort the table accordingly:</p>

<table id="myTable" class="w3-table-all">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Size</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm very grateful for the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49041392/1521064) and [jedwards' fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53880407/1521064), but I also find them poorly readable. So here's my refactored and verbose version:

```js
// Remember that strings are false positives for isNaN
const isEmptyOrNaN = (obj) => obj === "" || isNaN(obj);

const getCellValueInColumn = (tr, columnIdx) =>
  tr.children[columnIdx].innerText || tr.children[columnIdx].textContent;

const compareCellValues = (cellValue1, cellValue2) => {
  return isEmptyOrNaN(cellValue1) || isEmptyOrNaN(cellValue2)
    ? cellValue1.toString().localeCompare(cellValue2)
    : cellValue1 - cellValue2;
};

const compareFnFactory = (columnIdx, ascending) => (firstEl, secondEl) => {
  const cellValue1 = getCellValueInColumn(firstEl, columnIdx);
  const cellValue2 = getCellValueInColumn(secondEl, columnIdx);
  return ascending
    ? compareCellValues(cellValue1, cellValue2)
    : compareCellValues(cellValue2, cellValue1);
};

document.querySelectorAll("th").forEach((th) =>
  th.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const table = th.closest("table");
    const tbody = table.querySelector("tbody");
    const columnIdx = Array.from(th.parentNode.children).indexOf(th);
    const compareFn = compareFnFactory(columnIdx, (this.ascending = !this.ascending));
    Array.from(tbody.querySelectorAll("tr"))
      .sort(compareFn)
      .forEach((tr) => tbody.appendChild(tr));
  })
);
```

If you find any extra spaces or parenthesis, unnecessary indents, etc., it's because I've formatted the code with prettier.

I've wrapped this code inside a:

```js
javascript: (function () {
  // Code here
})();
```

and put it into a bookmarklet, so now I can sort columns inside Keycloak Admin Console.

Answer (score 1):

I took the freedom to enhance [Nick Grealy´s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49041392/782034)
with automated suffixing to display the sort order.

I also fixed a small bug I discovered after I got the suffixing working: When clicking on a column, that is sorted ascending. When then clicking on another column, that is sorted descending (in my Waterfox, at least). `this.asc` seems to be stored staticly in the function, not in the element. The patch uses a custom attribute on the `th` element, which is set for ascending and removed for descending.

Simply insert these lines right after the `const` definitions:

```js
    var asc = th.hasAttribute('sortAsc');
    th.closest('tr').querySelectorAll('th').forEach(th => {
        th.classList.remove('sort-asc');
        th.classList.remove('sort-desc');
        th.removeAttribute('sortAsc');
    });
    th.classList.add(asc=!asc?'sort-asc':'sort-desc');
    if (asc) th.setAttribute('sortAsc', '1');
```

and replace `this.asc = !this.asc` with `asc`.

the CSS:

```css
.sort-asc:after { content: ' ^'; } .sort-desc:after { content: ' v' }
```

---

Another idea was to reflect the stable sort: This variant does not remove the sort order from the previously sorted columns, but merely adds another CSS class to highlight the latest sort:

```js
    var asc = !th.hasAttribute('sortAsc');
    th.classList.remove(asc?'sort-desc':'sort-asc');
    th.classList.add(asc?'sort-asc':'sort-desc');
    th.closest('tr').querySelectorAll('th').forEach(th => { th.classList.remove('sort-current'); });
    th.classList.add('sort-current');
    asc ? th.setAttribute('sortAsc', 1) : th.removeAttribute('sortAsc');
```

plus additional CSS:

```css
.sort-current { background-color:green; }
```

Comment: Since almost half of the answers now are relating to Nick Grealy´s answer, I wanted to add titles so anyone can find stuff faster. But I discarded that idea when I found that the <h1> and <h2> from the markdown are more prominent than the actual page header (<h1 class="fs-headline1">).

Answer (score 0):

Sorting html table column on page load

```
var table = $('table#all_items_table');
var rows = table.find('tr:gt(0)').toArray().sort(comparer(3));
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    table.append(rows[i])
}
function comparer(index) {
    return function (a, b) {
        var v1= getCellValue(a, index),
        v2= getCellValue(b, index);
        return $.isNumeric(v2) && $.isNumeric(v1) ? v2 - v1: v2.localeCompare(v1)
    }
}


function getCellValue(row, index) {
    return parseFloat($(row).children('td').eq(index).html().replace(/,/g,'')); //1234234.45645->1234234
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have edited the code from one of the example here to use jquery.
It's still not 100% jquery though. Any thoughts on the two different versions, like ***what are the pros and cons of each***?

```
function column_sort() {
    getCellValue = (tr, idx) => $(tr).find('td').eq( idx ).text();

    comparer = (idx, asc) => (a, b) => ((v1, v2) => 
        v1 !== '' && v2 !== '' && !isNaN(v1) && !isNaN(v2) ? v1 - v2 : v1.toString().localeCompare(v2)
        )(getCellValue(asc ? a : b, idx), getCellValue(asc ? b : a, idx));
    
    table = $(this).closest('table')[0];
    tbody = $(table).find('tbody')[0];

    elm = $(this)[0];
    children = elm.parentNode.children;
    Array.from(tbody.querySelectorAll('tr')).sort( comparer(
        Array.from(children).indexOf(elm), table.asc = !table.asc))
        .forEach(tr => tbody.appendChild(tr) );
}

table.find('thead th').on('click', column_sort);
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  td , th {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100px;
  }
  th {
    background-color: lightgreen;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Array Sort</h2>

<p>Click the buttons to sort car objects on age.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var nameArrow = "", yearArrow = "";
var cars = [
  {type:"Volvo", year:2016},
  {type:"Saab", year:2001},
  {type:"BMW", year:2010}
];
yearACS = true;
function sortYear() {
  if (yearACS) {
    nameArrow = "";
    yearArrow = "";
    cars.sort(function(a,b) {
      return a.year - b.year;
    });
    yearACS = false;
  }else {
    nameArrow = "";
    yearArrow = "";
    cars.sort(function(a,b) {
      return b.year - a.year;
    });
    yearACS = true;
  }
  displayCars();
}
nameACS = true;
function sortName() {
  if (nameACS) {
    nameArrow = "";
    yearArrow = "";
    cars.sort(function(a,b) {
      x = a.type.toLowerCase();
      y = b.type.toLowerCase();
      if (x > y) {return 1;}
      if (x < y) {return -1};
      return 0;
    });
    nameACS = false;
  } else {
    nameArrow = "";
    yearArrow = "";
    cars.sort(function(a,b) {
      x = a.type.toUpperCase();
      y = b.type.toUpperCase();
      if (x > y) { return -1};
      if (x <y) { return 1 };
      return 0;
    });
    nameACS = true;
  }
  displayCars();
}

displayCars();

function displayCars() {
  var txt = "<table><tr><th onclick='sortName()'>name " + nameArrow + "</th><th onclick='sortYear()'>year " + yearArrow + "</th><tr>";
  for (let i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
    txt += "<tr><td>"+ cars[i].type + "</td><td>" + cars[i].year + "</td></tr>";
  }
  txt += "</table>";
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

I've found myself using @NickGrealy method to sort items and it works great!
(https://stackoverflow.com/a/49041392/18045902)

Issue I had is that i'm using a different format for date: dd-mm-YY instead of the ISO one.

As I'm passing data from a .php file as a string I had to convert the string in a date then compare with ><==

Substitute the compare function

```
// Returns a function responsible for sorting a specific column index 
// (idx = columnIndex, asc = ascending order?).
var comparer = function(idx, asc) { 

// This is used by the array.sort() function...
return function(a, b) { 

    // This is a transient function, that is called straight away. 
    // It allows passing in different order of args, based on 
    // the ascending/descending order.
    return function(v1, v2) {

        // sort based on a numeric or localeCompare, based on type...
        return (v1 !== '' && v2 !== '' && !isNaN(v1) && !isNaN(v2)) 
            ? v1 - v2 
            : v1.toString().localeCompare(v2);
    }(getCellValue(asc ? a : b, idx), getCellValue(asc ? b : a, idx));
}
```

};

with this:

```
    var comparer = function(idx, asc) { 

// This is used by the array.sort() function...
return function(a, b) { 

    // This is a transient function, that is called straight away. 
    // It allows passing in different order of args, based on 
    // the ascending/descending order.
    return function(v1, v2) {
        
        if(v1 !== '' && v2 !== '' && !isNaN(v1) && !isNaN(v2)){
            x = v1 - v2;
            console.log(v1); 
        } else if(v1.includes("-")) {
            var partsArray1 = v1.split('-');
            var partsArray2 = v2.split('-');
            var data1 = new Date(partsArray1[2],partsArray1[1],partsArray1[0]);
            var data2 = new Date(partsArray2[2],partsArray2[1],partsArray2[0]);
            if(data1>data2){
                x=1;
            } else if (data1<data2) {
                x=-1;
            } else if (data1==data2) {
                x=0;
            }
            

        } else {
            x = v1.toString().localeCompare(v2);
        }
        // sort based on a numeric or localeCompare, based on type...
        //return (v1 !== '' && v2 !== '' && !isNaN(v1) && !isNaN(v2)) 
        //    ? v1 - v2 
        //    : v1.toString().localeCompare(v2);

        return x;

    }(getCellValue(asc ? a : b, idx), getCellValue(asc ? b : a, idx));
}
};
```

NOTE: this will only work if the date you are trying to parse is a string in the dd-mm-YY format.
If you need a different format change the includes() and the split() character (in my case is "-") and the order of the date you are creating with Date().

If there's something wrong with this method please comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version, where I have cached `table`, `tbody`, `rows`, and `cellIndex` for better performance. I also make use of `replaceChildren`to avoid using `appendChild` in a loop.

```js
for (const table of document.getElementsByTagName("table")) {
  const tBody = table.tBodies[0];
  const rows = Array.from(tBody.rows);
  for (const th of table.tHead.rows[0].cells) {
    th.addEventListener("click", e => {
      const cellIndex = e.target.cellIndex;
      rows.sort((a, b) => a.cells[cellIndex].textContent.trim().localeCompare(b.cells[cellIndex].textContent.trim()));
      tBody.replaceChildren(...rows);
    });
  }
}
```

In the html `table` markup, for code to work, there should be exactly one `thead` element wrapping the `th` elements, and zero or at most one `tbody` element wrapping the `td`elements, since `tbody`can always be omitted according to the html standards. (Every `table` element has implicitly exactly one `tbody` element unless explicitly specified more.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the accepted answer as a complete html file, with script tag, style tag, and wrapped in window.onload function.
Just copy the text, paste it to notepad and save as page.html .
You could also add `<head>` before `<script>`, and closing tag `</head>` after `</style>` . But copying it as it is will also work. Tested it in firefox/windows.
Thanks to Nick Grealy, and Vladimir.
Note that first row in the table, has `<th>` (table header), not `<td>` (table data) tag.

```
    <script>
    window.onload=function(){ 
    const getCellValue = (tr, idx) => tr.children[idx].innerText || tr.children[idx].textContent;
    
    const comparer = (idx, asc) => (a, b) => ((v1, v2) => 
        v1 !== '' && v2 !== '' && !isNaN(v1) && !isNaN(v2) ? v1 - v2 : v1.toString().localeCompare(v2)
        )(getCellValue(asc ? a : b, idx), getCellValue(asc ? b : a, idx));
    
    // do the work...
    document.querySelectorAll('th').forEach(th => th.addEventListener('click', (() => {
        const table = th.closest('table');
        Array.from(table.querySelectorAll('tr:nth-child(n+2)'))
            .sort(comparer(Array.from(th.parentNode.children).indexOf(th), this.asc = !this.asc))
            .forEach(tr => table.appendChild(tr) );
    })));
    
    }
    </script>
    <style>
    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    th {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    </style>
    <table>
        <tr><th>Country</th><th>Date</th><th>Size</th></tr>
        <tr><td>France</td><td>2001-01-01</td><td><i>25</i></td></tr>
        <tr><td><a href=#>spain</a></td><td><i>2005-05-05</i></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td><b>Lebanon</b></td><td><a href=#>2002-02-02</a></td><td><b>-17</b></td></tr>
        <tr><td><i>Argentina</i></td><td>2005-04-04</td><td><a href=#>100</a></td></tr>
        <tr><td>USA</td><td></td><td>-6</td></tr>
    </table>
```

If you wish to add some color, and alternating rows color, use this as css style:

```
    <style>
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;

            /* width: 100%; */
        }
          
        th, td {
            text-align: left;
            padding: 8px;
        border: 1px solid green;
        }

    th {
            cursor: pointer;
            text-decoration: underline;
    }   
          
        tr:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: Beige;
        }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination of answers [Nick Grealy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49041392/5172715), [jedwards](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53880407/5172715) and [vault](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69921660/5172715) with some changes:

1. Works on Chrome version 30.0.0.0 ([released 2013-12-09](https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/2013/09/)) which is used in Android 4.4 [WebView](http://docs.52im.net/extend/docs/api/android-50/guide/webapps/migrating.html) (I needed it)
2. Column sorting is set for all tables on the page
3. Supported tables with `tbody` and without it
4. `th` and `td` headers are supported (although it seems to have already worked)

```
// use setTableSortCallbacks();

function setTableSortCallbacks() {
    const tables = document.querySelectorAll("table");
    for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
        const table = tables[i];
        if (table.rows.length > 0) {
            const cells = table.rows[0].cells;
            for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
                setCellCallback(table, cells[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}

function setCellCallback(table, cell) {
    cell.onclick = function() {
        sortTableByColumn(table, cell);
    };
}

function sortTableByColumn(table, cell) {
    const tbody = table.querySelector("tbody");
    const parent = (tbody != null) ? tbody : table;

    const rows = parent.querySelectorAll('tr:nth-child(n+2)');

    const rowsArray = toArray(rows);
    const compareFn = compareRowsFnFactory(cell.cellIndex, this.asc = !this.asc);
    rowsArray.sort(compareFn);
    for (var i = 0; i < rowsArray.length; i++) {
        parent.appendChild(rowsArray[i]);
    }
}

function compareRowsFnFactory(colIndex, asc) {
    return function(a, b) {
        const cellValue1 = getCellValue(a, colIndex);
        const cellValue2 = getCellValue(b, colIndex);
        return asc
            ? compareCellValues(cellValue1, cellValue2)
            : compareCellValues(cellValue2, cellValue1);
    };
}

function getCellValue(row, colIndex) {
    const cell = row.children[colIndex];
    return cell.innerText || cell.textContent;
}

function compareCellValues(cellValue1, cellValue2) {
    return isEmptyOrNaN(cellValue1) || isEmptyOrNaN(cellValue2)
        ? cellValue1.toString().localeCompare(cellValue2)
        : cellValue1 - cellValue2;
}

function isEmptyOrNaN(value) {
    return value === "" || isNaN(value);
}

function toArray(nodesList) {
    var arr = [];
    for(var i = 0, node; node = nodesList[i]; ++i) {
        arr.push(node);
    }
    return arr;
}
```