# A switch between ascending and descending table rows on a tableheader click

Tags: php, sorting

I've been messing with this for quite some time now, but I just can't get it to work. What I'm trying to make is ;

A clickable table header, that once clicked switches the row order from ascending to descending and back when clicked again.

The attempts I did so far didn't loop, and got stuck after one click.

Comment: How does this relate to PHP? Do you want to do the sorting on server-side? If not, then it's a JavaScript question and should be described as such.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  Google has 1 million results for `php javascript sort html table`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting HTML table with JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267781/sorting-html-table-with-js)

Comment: The thing is that I'm trying to do this without javascript. Just a switch that edits the query from ascending to descending and back on click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a link to your table header cell which contains a parameter, e.g.

```
<tr><th>
   <a href="currentpage.php?order=<?php echo isset($_GET['order'])?!$_GET['order']:1; ?>">
      Name
   </a>
</th></tr>
```

What happens here? A link will be added, containing an `order` parameter which is set to the opposite of the current `order` value(1/true or 0/false) or to 1 as default.

In your PHP script you can now decide how to order your table using the `order` value:

```
$isAsc = isset($_GET['order'])? (bool) $_GET['order']: 1;
```

Now you can use the `$isAsc` boolean:

```
if ($isAsc) {
   // Sort data ascending
} else {
   // Sort data descending
}
```

Or in a query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tabe ORDER BY name ".($isAsc?"ASC":"DESC").";";
```

Of course, you can extend this idea, e.g., by adding column names to sort by several columns.

Comment: Hello Andre, can you kindly help implementing this concept in this question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/45628071/3446280 thank you for any. But please note that my pages are already `.php` .

Comment: Hi Robert. Rudy already updated the given solution, so it combines column and the sorting parameter. If you have further questions or the given solution still does not work for you, feel free to ask!