# HTML TABLE PHP MySQL toggle MySQL sorting order ASC DESC on column header click

Tags: php, html, mysql

**EDIT**: added solution from the accepted answer

The hint I'm asking here is the smartest method for.

Need to be said first: I kindly ask you to avoid suggesting databales and similar.

I'm displaying a MySQL table content in a HTML table.

I have the view that is `showdbtable.php` which uses as include `echohtmltable.php` which queries the database and echoes the table rows.

So in `echohtmltable.php` currently there is quite everything involved in this question

GET variable check

```
if(isset($_GET['sortby'])){
    $sortby=$_GET['sortby'];
    $_GET['sortby']=''; }
else { 
    $sortby="id_ord"; }
```

and the consequent query

```
$query = "
        SELECT id_ord, fornitore, negozio, data_insord, data_prevcons 
        FROM tesord 
        ORDER BY ".$sortby." DESC 
        LIMIT :from_record_num, :records_per_page";
```

which next is used to echo the table rows creating also the sort mechanism in the columns headers

```
echo "<th>".'<a href="showdbtable.php?sortby=fornitore">' . "Fornitore</th>";
echo "<th>".'<a href="showdbtable.php?sortby=negozio">' . "Negozio</th>";
echo "<th>".'<a href="showdbtable.php?sortby=data_insord">' . "Data_insord</th>";
echo "<th>".'<a href="showdbtable.php?sortby=data_prevcons">' . "Data_prevcons</th>";
```

as you know this first part works.

When I click one of the above links, the query works but currently as obvious from the code, in DESC only.

The kind request is a suggestion altogether. But PLEASE also NOTE that I have pagination, you see, `LIMIT :from_record_num, :records_per_page` , that should be taken in consideration.

Which is the smartest and efficient way to toggle between ASC and DESC in such a way that after having clicked one link, e.g. "Negozio", clicking again "Negozio" it goes sorted in ASC, and next click it will toggle DESC, and next click ASC and so on.

I'm sure the query will mutate in having a variable I may call $ascdesc

```
$query = "
        SELECT id_ord, fornitore, negozio, data_insord, data_prevcons 
        FROM tesord 
        ORDER BY " . $sortby . " " . $ascdesc . " 
        LIMIT :from_record_num, :records_per_page";
```

need to manage if currently is ASC or DESC and toggle.

Thank you for hinting on some efficient and smart method to achieve the goal.

---

**Solution**: thank you to Rudy

For the sake of helping others newbies like me, here is how I have applied the solution

```
// function used in the links
function invdir($dir){ return ($dir == "DESC")? "ASC" : "DESC"; }
// self explaining, it does invert the sort string in the link

// collect, sanitize and default $_GET variables. 
// $ordinaper is the Italian of $sortby
$ordinaper = (isset($_GET['ordinaper']))? (filter_var($_GET["ordinaper"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)) : "id_ord";
$ascdesc = (isset($_GET['ascdesc']))? (filter_var($_GET["ascdesc"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)) : "DESC";
// $filtraforn is a filter/search to show only one provider, see the query, it is assigned with a ìn AJAX live search
$filtraforn = (isset($_GET['filtraforn']))? (filter_var($_GET["filtraforn"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)) : "";

// build the common URL GET part
$getlinks = "&filtraforn=".$filtraforn."&page=".$page."&ascdesc=";
// the variable $page comes from the pagination which is out of the scope. Here I was dealing with the correct management of sorting the HTML table columns

// the query is built accordingly, later is used in a PDO statement
$query = "SELECT id_ord, fornitore, negozio, data_insord, data_prevcons FROM tesord ";
$filtro = (strlen($filtraforn))? "WHERE fornitore = '" . $filtraforn . "' " : "";
$query = $query . $filtro . "ORDER BY ". $ordinaper ." ". $ascdesc ." LIMIT :from_record_num, :records_per_page";
// LIMIT :from_record_num, :records_per_page are bound later with variables coming from the pagination which is out of the scope. Here I was dealing with the correct management of sorting the HTML table columns

// and here it is the final table heading
// the ternary operator (($ordinaper!=="id_ord")? "DESC" : invdir($ascdesc)) is used because when clicking a different column, I want to default the sorting in DESC
echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th></th>";
    echo "<th>". '<a href="read.php?ordinaper=id_ord' .$getlinks. (($ordinaper!=="id_ord")? "DESC" : invdir($ascdesc)) .'">' . "id_ord</th>";
    echo "<th>". '<a href="read.php?ordinaper=ord_evaso' .$getlinks. (($ordinaper!=="ord_evaso")? "DESC" : invdir($ascdesc)) .'">' . "Stato</th>";
    echo "<th>". '<a href="read.php?ordinaper=fornitore' .$getlinks. (($ordinaper!=="fornitore")? "DESC" : invdir($ascdesc)) .'">' . "Fornitore</th>";
    echo "<th>". '<a href="read.php?ordinaper=negozio' .$getlinks. (($ordinaper!=="negozio")? "DESC" : invdir($ascdesc)) .'">' . "Negozio</th>";
    echo "<th>". '<a href="read.php?ordinaper=data_insord' .$getlinks. (($ordinaper!=="data_insord")? "DESC" : invdir($ascdesc)) .'">' . "Data_insord</th>";
    echo "<th>". '<a href="read.php?ordinaper=data_prevcons' .$getlinks. (($ordinaper!=="data_prevcons")? "DESC" : invdir($ascdesc)) .'">' . "Data_prevcons</th>";
    echo "<th>Paia Inev.</th>";
    echo "<th>Azione</th>";
echo "</tr>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are already sending the
   sortby
via GET, why wouldn't you send the
    ASC,DESC
Option too, I mean, you could use 1 and 0 instead of the actual ASC/DESC and toggle it inside your code,for example:

```
$ascdesc = ($_GET['ad'])? '0' : '1';
```

And just add the var to the link

```
echo "<th>".'<a href="showdbtable.php?sortby=negozio&ad='.$ascdesc.'">' . "Negozio</th>";
```

And in you query, something like

```
 $ascdesc = ($_GET['ad'])? 'asc' : 'desc';
```

Something very important here is that if you are accepting user input via GET, you have to sanitize the var to avoid SQL injections, don't forget this.

**UPDATE:**

*Possible implementation with your own code:*

```
$sortby = (isset($_GET['sortby']))? $_GET['sortby'] : "id_ord";
$ascdesc = ($_GET['ad']=='asc')? 'ASC' : 'DESC';
```

The Query:

```
$query = "SELECT id_ord, fornitore, negozio, data_insord, data_prevcons 
          FROM tesord 
          ORDER BY ".$sortby." ".$ascdesc." 
          LIMIT :from_record_num, :records_per_page";
```

The link:

```
echo "<th>".'<a href="showdbtable.php?sortby=fornitore&ad=<?=(($_GET['ad']=='asc')? 'desc' : 'asc';)?>">' . "Fornitore</th>";
```

And if you need to add the page, just add the current page and change sort, you can add a var also to the link

```
echo "<th>".'<a href="showdbtable.php?sortby=fornitore&ad=<?php echo (($_GET['ad']=='asc')? 'desc' : 'asc';)?>&page=<?php echo $_GET['page]?>">' . "Fornitore</th>";
```

There are many other ways to handle the pagination and sorting, but I think that, without getting into a lot of trouble, this could be a way, however, about the security, you can use [mysql_real_escape](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

You could also leave everything to javascript/jQuery by implementing something like [this](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)

Hope this can give you a better understanding, happy coding.

Comment: Ouch, can you kindly explain the first line of code? `$ascdesc = ($_GET['ad'])? '0' : '1';` . Thank you.

Comment: Though, because of pagination I begin feeling that the solution will pass through sessions or cookies.

Comment: It is a ternary operator, [you can find more examples here](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators), but basically it is an IF but as shorthand, it means `if($_GET['ad']){ $ascdesc =  '0'; }else{ $ascdesc = '1'; }` where `($_GET['ad'])` is true or in this case: 1, even if you are using cookies or sessions, the logic its almost the same, if it is defined, toggle to 0, if it is undefined or 0, toggle to 1

Comment: As you may guess I'm still almost newbie. So allow me to ask you an implementation example of your code, since I am not able to understand how your code would retain the current sorting order and toggle it at the next click. Thank you for helping. I mean, do you mean that your method works without sessions or cookies?

Comment: (continues from previous comment) I'll also have to handle the pagination :-( . When you click on (e.g.) page 2, the URL changes to url?page=2 so no more sortby and ascdesc. Mmmh I need to work on this too. But this makes me think even more I have to store these variables in a place that goes not lost after the clicks and url changes. How would you handle that?

Comment: And now I'm also thinking: if we currently are in page 3 and we click to sort by on any column: would you reset to page 1 or would you keep current page 3? (I know it is matter of my decision, but your point of view is welcome.

Comment: Check the light implementation, hope it helps

Comment: Thank you really much for the update. Today is holiday here so I'll try it as soon as possible. Meanwhile I'm reading the code. So does it mean this works without _SESSION and without coockies? Right? I'll try to understand the mechanism you have used, e.g. if is _GET that remains available either after a page reload or what :-)

Comment: Thank you for all the explanations! Finally I had the chance to apply the code and get the idea of how it works. One last hint, how would you reset the ascdesc order to DESC when clicking on another column? Since currently it depends on the previous reverse. I mean if last click sorted to DESC one of the columns, clicking a different one makes it ASC while I'd like to default it to DESC (on the first click, column change).

Comment: About resetting the ascdesc, I solved it with a nested ternary operator (thank for having explained it) in the link building `(($sortby!=="id_ord")? "DESC" : (($ascdesc == "DESC")? "ASC" : "DESC"))`. I compare each current sortby and if it is different I default to DESC, otherwise .. inversion .. ;-)

Comment: I made it shorter with a function.

Answer (score 0):

Before seeing these postings, I came up with a simple ASC/DESC sorter that added only two lines of code:

```
$SortType = (isset($_GET['SortType']) && $_GET['SortType'] === "DESC") ? "ASC" : "DESC";
$SortOrder = "ORDER BY `StorageArea` $SortType";
```

then I appended this to the query (the dots are indicating the earlier part of the query that is not shown here):

```
... $SortOrder";
```

and the link has:

```
<a href="/index.php?SortOrder=StorageArea&SortType=<?=$SortType;?>" id="Sorter_StorageArea">Storage</a>
```