# Django - change Dictsort using a Javascript onclick listener?

Tags: javascript, django, sorting, onclick

Is it possible to change what `dictsort` is sorting by using Javascript?

Here is my sort code:

```
{% for product in products|dictsortreversed:'price' %}
    ....stuff happening here
{% endfor %}
```

What I want is for when a user clicks on a sort option for the `dictsortreversed:'price'` to become `dictsort:'price'`.

Is this possible at all? Or should I try and find a different way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in a direct way, because `dictsort` and `dictsortreversed` are [template filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#built-in-filter-reference) that Django applies at rendering time in the server, and Javascript is executed in the client browser after rendering an cannot influence rendering inside the server.

Proven methods you could use:

1. Make a new HTTP request when the user selects a sort option and pass this sort option as a HTTP GET parameter (query string parameter), and modify your Django view to sort the data according to that param (maybe by calling `order_by` on the `QuerySet`).

   **Conditional sorting is better done at the view level, not in your templates.**
2. Use dynamic sorting through Javascript, maybe by employing tested tools like [datatables](https://datatables.net/) or similar ones (Google will gladly help you with that).
   See also [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267781/sorting-html-table-with-javascript) about sorting with Javascript.