# jQuery table sort with prefix and date as string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Building off of Nick Grealy's answer here: [Sorting HTML table with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267781/sorting-html-table-with-javascript/49041392#comment90432383_49041392) , I added additional `sort criteria` typical for most `tables`.

To help people looking for an all in one sort handling solution, what is the best way to sort `prefixes` and `delimiters`, and `date as a string`?

Additionally, should `RegEx` be used to recognize the delimiter used for `thousands`?

```js
const getCellValue = (tr, idx) =>
  tr.children[idx].innerText || tr.children[idx].textContent;

const comparer = (idx, asc) => (a, b) =>
  ((v1, v2) =>
    v1 !== "" && v2 !== "" && !isNaN(v1) && !isNaN(v2) ?
    v1 - v2 :
    v1.toString().localeCompare(v2))(
    getCellValue(asc ? a : b, idx),
    getCellValue(asc ? b : a, idx)
  );

// do the work...
document.querySelectorAll("th").forEach(th =>
  th.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const table = th.closest("table");
    Array.from(table.querySelectorAll("tr:nth-child(n+2)"))
      .sort(
        comparer(
          Array.from(th.parentNode.children).indexOf(th),
          (this.asc = !this.asc)
        )
      )
      .forEach(tr => table.appendChild(tr));
  })
);
```

```css
th {
  cursor: pointer
}

td {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Date (text)</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>France</td>
    <td>2018-04-03</td>
    <td>Apr 03, 2018 10:30PM</td>
    <td>$2500</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>spain</td>
    <td>2018-03-05</td>
    <td>Mar 05, 2018 12:19PM</td>
    <td>$11,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lebanon</td>
    <td>2018-03-05</td>
    <td>Mar 05, 2018 04:30AM</td>
    <td>$980</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Argentina</td>
    <td>2018-09-13</td>
    <td>Sept 13, 2018 01:50AM</td>
    <td>$8100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>USA</td>
    <td>2017-012-17</td>
    <td>Dec 17, 2017 11:30AM</td>
    <td>$6000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```