# Javascript coloring rows based on MySQL date values and today

Tags: javascript, mysql

I'm showing MySQL table results on my page and I'm trying to highlight the rows where the Next review date is earlier than today's date, these rows should be colored red (later I would want another coloring as well, today+10 days should be in orange). I know that I would need to use Javascript for that, however, I have tried 10+ solutions but none of them are working, could you help me? The Next review date is in date format in phpmyadmin (YYYY-MM-DD).

Here is what I have tried currently (the id of my table is table):

```
var table = document.getElementById("table");
      for(var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i ++) {
        var status = new Date(table.rows[i].cells[4].innerHTML).getTime();
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        console.log(now>status)
        if (now>status) { 
            table.rows[i].style.background = "red";
        } 
        };
```

If you would need more code or explanation please indicate it and I will edit the post. Thank you very much for your help!

This is how the table looks like now (coloring was never successful):

```
if ($_SESSION['user_type'] == 'admin') {
    echo '<div class="table" id="table"> <table>
        <tr>
        <th>
            <a href="?orderBy=name">Asset name</a>
        </th>
        <th>
            <a href="?orderBy=classification">Classification</a>
        </th>   
        <th>
            <a href="?orderBy=tag">Tag</a>
        </th>
        <th>
            <a href="?orderBy=department">Department</a>
        </th>   
        <th>
            <a href="?orderBy=nextreview">Next review date</a>
        </th>   
        <th>
            <a href="?orderBy=responsible">Responsible</a>
        </th>   
        <th>Update</th>
        </tr>';


    $sql = "SELECT * 
    FROM `assets`
    ORDER BY id";

    if (isset($_GET['orderBy'])) {
        $orderby = $_GET['orderBy'];

        if ($orderby == 'name')
        {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `assets`ORDER BY Asset_name";
        }
        elseif ($orderby == 'classification')
        {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `assets`ORDER BY Classification";
        }
        elseif ($orderby == 'tag')
        {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `assets`ORDER BY Tag";
        }
        elseif($orderby == 'department')
        {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `assets`ORDER BY Department";
        }
        elseif($orderby == 'nextreview')
        {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `assets` ORDER BY Review_date asc";
        }
        elseif($orderby == 'responsible')
        {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `assets`ORDER BY Responsible";
        }
    }
    if (!($result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql)))
    { die("Could not show the required data" . mysqli_error($conn));}
    elseif (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

        while($result2=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {echo '<tr>
        <td>'.$result2["Asset_name"].'</td>
        <td>'.$result2["Classification"].'</td>
        <td>'.$result2["Tag"].'</td>
        <td>'.$result2["Department"].'</td>
        <td class="status">'.$result2["Review_date"].'</td>
        <td>'.$result2["Responsible"].'</td>
        <td><a href="editassets.php?id='.$result2['id'].'">Edit</a> | <a href="deleteassets.php?id='.$result2['id'].'" onclick="return confirm(\'Do you want to delete this asset?\');">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>';
        }
        echo '</table></div>';
        }
```

Current look:

[image]

Comment: Please add an example of the table in HTML, which does not give the expected coloring.

Comment: I have added a picture of my current table

Comment: Please, not a picture. Type the plain HTML code *in* your question indented with at least 4 spaces. That will allow us to run your code on that particular HTML and see where it goes wrong.

Comment: Ok, I have updated it with my table code

Comment: The problem is that your element with `id="table"` is NOT the table, but a parent `div`. And of course that element does not have a `rows` property. Your code would produce an error in the console. Did you check the console?

Comment: no, I havent checked it. How should I solve the issue then, could you please help me?

Comment: In your HTML, move the `id="table"` attribute from the `div` to the `table` element. And, please, make it a habit to work with the console. It is a must for any browser based development.

Comment: I would get in the practice of using AJAX JavaScript to get information from PHP. Just a comment. By the way, I don't see you comparing your reviewDate with today's date in a query before adding your `status` className. You cannot rely on Client time, as it can be altered, which in your case would just show the wrong status.

Comment: PS: Looking at the picture of your table, your contrast on the header is VERY poor - @trincot: The picture would have saved a lot of time since it shows the date format. A picture is ALWAYS welcome in these cases AS LONG as there is code too

Comment: @mplungjan, sure, just that there was neither at first, and then *only* the picture. And that picture did not show the main problem there was with the `id` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

- The **table** should have the ID of table, not some wrapper - please wrap the THs in a THEAD and the rest of the table in TBODY
- I use a class instead of background colour
- I use querySelectorAll to get the cells directly
- I use string comparison. MUCH faster than date comparison

> Scroll down for a version that is compatible with older IEs
>   Scroll further down for a sortable table

```js
// setup
const pad = (num) => ("0" + num).slice(-2);
const now = new Date();
const nowString = now.getFullYear() + "-" + pad(now.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + pad(now.getDate());

// loop
// remove closest("tr"). to just highlight the cell

[...document.querySelectorAll("table tr td:nth-child(5)")].forEach(cell =>
  cell.closest("tr").classList.toggle("red", nowString > cell.textContent.trim())
);
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: none;
}

tr  th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><a href="?orderBy=name">Asset name</a></th>
      <th><a href="?orderBy=classification">Classification</a></th>
      <th><a href="?orderBy=tag">Tag</a></th>
      <th><a href="?orderBy=department">Department</a></th>
      <th><a href="?orderBy=nextreview">Next review date</a></th>
      <th><a href="?orderBy=responsible">Responsible</a></th>
      <th>Update</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>2019-07-08</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>2019-07-09</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>2019-07-10</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>2019-07-11</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>2021-07-10</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>2022-07-11</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

ES<5 version

```js
// setup
var pad = (num) => ("0" + num).slice(-2);
var now = new Date();
var nowString = now.getFullYear() + "-" + pad(now.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + pad(now.getDate());

// loop

var cells = document.querySelectorAll("table tr td:nth-child(5)")

for (var i=0;i<cells.length;i++) {
  var row = cells[i].parentNode; // use cells[i].classList to just highlight the cell
  row.classList.toggle("red", nowString > cells[i].textContent.trim())
}
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: none;
}

tr  th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><a href="?orderBy=name">Asset name</a></th>
      <th><a href="?orderBy=classification">Classification</a></th>
      <th><a href="?orderBy=tag">Tag</a></th>
      <th><a href="?orderBy=department">Department</a></th>
      <th><a href="?orderBy=nextreview">Next review date</a></th>
      <th><a href="?orderBy=responsible">Responsible</a></th>
      <th>Update</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>2019-07-08</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>2019-07-09</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>2019-07-10</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>2019-07-11</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>2021-07-10</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>2022-07-11</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Sortable

[Sorting HTML table with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267781/sorting-html-table-with-javascript)

Note the numeric cells will be sorted alphabetically here, more code needed to handle the `90` below

```js
// setup
const pad = (num) => ("0" + num).slice(-2);
const now = new Date();
const nowString = now.getFullYear() + "-" + pad(now.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + pad(now.getDate());

// loop
// remove closest("tr"). to just highlight the cell

[...document.querySelectorAll("table tr td:nth-child(5)")].forEach(cell =>
  cell.closest("tr").classList.toggle("red", nowString > cell.textContent.trim())
);

function sortTable(table, col, reverse) {
    var tb = table.tBodies[0], // use `<tbody>` to ignore `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` rows
        tr = Array.prototype.slice.call(tb.rows, 0), // put rows into array
        i;
    reverse = -((+reverse) || -1);
    tr = tr.sort(function (a, b) { // sort rows
        return reverse // `-1 *` if want opposite order
            * (a.cells[col].textContent.trim() // using `.textContent.trim()` for test
                .localeCompare(b.cells[col].textContent.trim())
               );
    });
    for(i = 0; i < tr.length; ++i) tb.appendChild(tr[i]); // append each row in order
}
function makeSortable(table) {
    var th = table.tHead, i;
    th && (th = th.rows[0]) && (th = th.cells);
    if (th) i = th.length;
    else return; // if no `<thead>` then do nothing
    while (--i >= 0) (function (i) {
        var dir = 1;
        th[i].addEventListener('click', function () {sortTable(table, i, (dir = 1 - dir))});
    }(i));
}
makeSortable(document.getElementById("table"))
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: none;
}

tr  th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Asset name</th>
      <th>Classification</th>
      <th>Tag</th>
      <th>Department</th>
      <th>Next review date</th>
      <th>Responsible</th>
      <th>Update</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>200</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>2019-07-08</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>2019-07-10</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Q</td>
      <td>111</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>2019-07-11</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Z</td>
      <td>302</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>2021-07-10</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>V</td>
      <td>90</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>2022-07-11</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>N</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>2019-07-09</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Here I can see that your solution is working, I have changed everything to be the same as your solution but it is still not working:(

Comment: It is YYYY-MM-DD for example 2019-07-02

Comment: Wow, thanks for your help. I might be the stupidest person on Earth but even copy pasting your JS and CSS code have not helped me, I have still the issue :( I have deleted cookies as well, tried everything, but nothing has changed:(

Comment: Go to my profile and send me a link to your site. Perhaps I can see why

Answer (score 0):

As others start answering, I will post what I discussed with you in comments:

Your HTML has:

```
<div class="table" id="table"> <table>
```

Your JavaScript however defines:

```
var table = document.getElementById("table");
```

... and continues to treat that `table` as the table element, but it isn't. In your HTML you can see it is a `<div>` element, not a `<table>` element.

So align both. Either change your HTML, so that the `<table>` has the `id="table"`:

```
<div class="table"> <table  id="table">
```

... or change your JavaScript so that it takes the *child* element of the `<div>` with that id:

```
var table = document.getElementById("table").firstElementChild;
```

NB: Don't make *both* changes: choose the one that best suits you.