# How to Sort a numeric HTML table column at defult using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, columnsorting

I have this table

```
   <table name="mytable" id="mytable">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>LastName</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Dean</td>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>Tank</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Jean</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Ted</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Frank</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>Marie</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Kid</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>Arnold</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Ted</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>Marie</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Ma</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>Jack</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Martin</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>Harvey</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Nelson</td>
        <td>16</td>
        <td>Tom</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

So I'm trying to display it with the column age sorted in descending order. I have not found any solution to this. The solutions I have found seem to be for alphabetic columns.

The biggest problem is actually having the table displayed with the column **Age** already sorted in descending order without the user having to tap on a header or button to sort it.

Comment: is the data static or created dynamically?

Comment: If it's a static table, well, it's small, so sort it manually!   If the person objects are added dynamically in Javascript, then sort them before adding them to the table markup.

Comment: As john already said sort them before adding to table or alternatively add them to table and then run your sorting function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting HTML table with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267781/sorting-html-table-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a solution using this script

```
<script>
function sortTable(){
var sorted = $('#myTable tbody tr').sort(function(a, b) {
  var a = $(a).find('td:first-child + td').text(), b = $(b).find('td:first-child + td').text();
  return b.localeCompare(a, false, {numeric: true})
})

$('#myTable').html(sorted);
}
sortTable();
</script>
```