# PHP Results Table With Sorting and Filtering

Tags: php, html

I have some code that sorts a php results table by clicking on the headers. I added filtering to this code so I can filter the results and then I want to be able to sort the filered results. I can sort the table when it is first populated and then I can filter the results but I cant sort the filtered results. The form action approved_vendor_criteria_CopyA_filter is identical to the code with the only exception being that in  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) i change $result to $search_result and I can filter but when I sort those filtered resuls the table re-populates with all the unfiltered results.

I have tried adjusting the code but I can not get it to work.

```
    <form action="approved_vendor_criteria_CopyA_filter.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="valueToSearch" placeholder="Value To Search"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="search" value="Filter"><br><br>


    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['search']))
    {
    $valueToSearch = $_POST['valueToSearch'];
   // search in all table columns
  // using concat mysql function
   $query = "SELECT * FROM `approved_vendor_criteria` WHERE CONCAT(`RM_Code`, `Status`, `COA_Description`, `Distributor_Name`, `Distributor_ID`,    `Distributor_Code`, `MFG_Name`, `MFG_ID`, `MFG_Code`, `Container_Type`, `Container_Capacity`, `Container_Capacity_Units`, `Approved_Vendor_Criteria_Table_ID`)      LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);

    }
     else {
       $query = "SELECT * FROM `approved_vendor_criteria`";
      $search_result = filterTable($query);
    }

    // function to connect and execute the query
    function filterTable($query)
    {
        $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "db");
        $filter_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
        return $filter_Result;
    }

        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "db");

        $orderBy = "RM_Code";
        $order = "asc";

        if(!empty($_GET["orderby"])) {
            $orderBy = $_GET["orderby"];
        }
        if(!empty($_GET["order"])) {
        $order = $_GET["order"];
        }

        $RM_CodeNextOrder = "asc";
        $StatusNextOrder = "asc";
        $COA_DescriptionNextOrder = "desc";
        $Distributor_NameNextOrder = "desc";
        $Distributor_IDNextOrder = "desc";
        $Distributor_CodeNextOrder = "desc";
        $MFG_NameNextOrder = "desc";
        $MFG_IDNextOrder = "desc";
        $MFG_CodeNextOrder = "desc";
        $Container_TypeNextOrder = "desc";
        $Container_CapacityNextOrder = "desc";
        $Container_Capacity_UnitsNextOrder = "desc";
        $Approved_Vendor_Criteria_Table_IDNextOrder = "desc";


        if($orderBy == "RM_Code" and $order == "asc") {
            $RM_CodeNextOrder = "desc";
        }
        if($orderBy == "Status" and $order == "asc") {
            $StatusNextOrder = "desc";
        }
        if($orderBy == "COA_Description" and $order == "desc") {
            $COA_DescriptionNextOrder = "asc";
        }
        if($orderBy == "Distributor_Name" and $order == "desc") {
            $Distributor_NameNextOrder = "asc";
        }
        if($orderBy == "Distributor_ID" and $order == "desc") {
            $Distributor_IDNextOrder = "asc";
        }
        if($orderBy == "Distributor_Code" and $order == "desc") {
            $Distributor_CodeNextOrder = "asc";
        }
        if($orderBy == "MFG_Name" and $order == "desc") {
            $MFG_NameNextOrder = "asc";
        }
        if($orderBy == "MFG_ID" and $order == "desc") {
            $MFG_IDNextOrder = "asc";
        }
        if($orderBy == "MFG_Code" and $order == "desc") {
            $MFG_CodeNextOrder = "asc";
        }
        if($orderBy == "Container_Type" and $order == "desc") {
            $Container_TypeNextOrder = "asc";
        }
        if($orderBy == "Container_Capacity" and $order == "desc") {
            $Container_CapacityNextOrder = "asc";
        }
        if($orderBy == "Container_Capacity_Units" and $order == "desc") {
            $Container_Capacity_UnitsNextOrder = "asc";
        }
        if($orderBy == "Approved_Vendor_Criteria_Table_ID" and $order == "desc") {
            $Approved_Vendor_Criteria_Table_IDNextOrder = "asc";
        }


        $sql = "SELECT * from approved_vendor_criteria ORDER BY " . $orderBy . " " . $order;
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

        ?>

        <html>
        <head>
           <title>Approved Vendor Criteria</title>      
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

        <style>
        .table-content{border-top:#CCCCCC 4px solid; width:50%;}
        .table-content th {padding:5px 20px; background: #F0F0F0;vertical-align:top;} 
        .table-content td {padding:5px 20px; border-bottom: #F0F0F0 1px solid;vertical-align:top;} 
        .column-title {text-decoration:none; color:#09f;}
        </style>
        </head>

        <body>
       <div class="demo-content">
    <h2 class="title_with_link">Approved Vendor Criteria</h2>
      <form name="frmSearch" method="post" action="">

    <?php if(!empty($result))    { ?>


    <table class="table-content">
            <thead>

            <tr>
      <th width="10%"><span><a href="?orderby=RM_Code&order=<?php echo $RM_CodeNextOrder; ?>" class="column-title">RM_Code</a></span></th>
      <th width="10%"><span><a href="?orderby=Status&order=<?php echo $StatusNextOrder; ?>" class="column-title">Status</a></span></th>          
      <th width="30%"><span><a href="?orderby=COA_Description&order=<?php echo $COA_DescriptionNextOrder; ?>" class="column-title">COA_Description</a></span></th>            <th width="20%"><span><a href="?orderby=Distributor_Name&order=<?php echo $Distributor_NameNextOrder; ?>" class="column-      title">Distributor_Name</a></span></th>
      <th width="10%"><span><a href="?orderby=Distributor_ID&order=<?php echo $Distributor_IDNextOrder; ?>" class="column-title">Distributor_ID</a></span></th>
      <th width="10%"><span><a href="?orderby=Distributor_Code&order=<?php echo $Distributor_CodeNextOrder; ?>" class="column-      title">Distributor_Code</a></span></th>
      <th width="10%"><span><a href="?orderby=MFG_Name&order=<?php echo $MFG_NameNextOrder; ?>" class="column-title">MFG_Name</a></span></th>
      <th width="10%"><span><a href="?orderby=MFG_ID&order=<?php echo $MFG_IDNextOrder; ?>" class="column-title">MFG_ID</a></span></th>
      <th width="10%"><span><a href="?orderby=MFG_Code&order=<?php echo $MFG_CodeNextOrder; ?>" class="column-title">MFG_Code</a></span></th>
      <th width="10%"><span><a href="?orderby=Container_Type&order=<?php echo $Container_TypeNextOrder; ?>" class="column-title">Container_Type</a></span></th>
      <th width="10%"><span><a href="?orderby=Container_Capacity&order=<?php echo $Container_CapacityNextOrder; ?>" class="column-      title">Container_Capacity</a></span></th>
      <th width="10%"><span><a href="?orderby=Container_Capacity_Units&order=<?php echo $Container_Capacity_UnitsNextOrder; ?>" class="column-      title">Container_Capacity_Units</a></span></th>
      <th width="10%"><span><a href="?orderby=Approved_Vendor_Criteria_Table_ID&order=<?php echo $Approved_Vendor_Criteria_Table_IDNextOrder; ?>" class="column-        title">Approved_Vendor_Criteria_Table_ID</a></span></th>

            </tr>
       </thead>

        <tbody>

    <?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 

    {
        ?>

           <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row["RM_Code"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["Status"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["COA_Description"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["Distributor_Name"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["Distributor_ID"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["Distributor_Code"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["MFG_Name"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["MFG_ID"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["MFG_Code"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["Container_Type"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["Container_Capacity"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["Container_Capacity_Units"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["Approved_Vendor_Criteria_Table_ID"]; ?></td>
        </tr>

     <?php
            }
       ?>
       <tbody>
      </table>
    <?php } ?>
      </form>
     </div>
    </body></html>
```

Comment: It’s probably helpful to have an `order by` in the query you use...

Answer (score 0):

Please forgive this answer - I truly do not like answers that attempt to direct us in a different direction than the original question; however, this is important enough that I believe you should consider looking into this as a possibility.

You should truly consider writing some javascript to re-sort the table when the user clicks on a column header.

Doing the sorting in PHP would require the page to totally reload, which would take time, even more so if it's a complex query or large result dataset.

In javascript, it would happen virtually instantaneously, without the user having to wait for the request to be sent to the server, the server to process the request, then send the resulting re-sorted table (and entire page) back to the client.

w3cschools has instructions on how to do this here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sort_table.asp

There is also another StackOverflow article on this here: [Sorting HTML table with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267781/sorting-html-table-with-javascript)

I've looked over both articles and they seem to be sources I would use for this issue. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried the script you referenced me to . However when I use it on a table that is past a certain size it stops working. Any suggestions.

Comment: Datatables is the way to go. Thanks