# Sorting HTML Tables in JavaScript using Regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm trying to make a HTML table sorting system in JavaScript. All I want is to sort each column by clicking on it, but I think I have to use regex to do so. You see, I want to sort numbers (0-9) first, then sort it alphabetically (a-z) then everything else (special characters) and last empty cells.

This is the order it has to go.

```
1
03
5
data
data1
-data
-data1
*empty cells*
*empty cells*
```

The code underneath can only sort the empty cells to the bottom (**Code currently taken from [Sorting HTML table with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267781/sorting-html-table-with-javascript/49041392#49041392)**):

```
var getCellValue = function(tr, idx) {
    return tr.children[idx].innerText || tr.children[idx].textContent;
}

var comparer = function(idx, asc) {
    return function(a, b) {
        return function(v1, v2) {
            if (v1 == "")
                return 1;
            if (v2 == "")
                return -1;
            return v1 != "" && v2 != "" && !isNaN(v1) && !isNaN(v2) ? v1 - v2 : v1.toString().localeCompare(v2);
        }(getCellValue(asc ? a : b, idx), getCellValue(asc ? b : a, idx));
    }
};

Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("th.sortable")).forEach(function(th) {
    th.addEventListener("click", function() {
        var table = th.parentNode
        var tbody = document.querySelector("tbody")
        while (table.tagName.toUpperCase() != "TABLE") table = table.parentNode;
        Array.prototype.slice.call(tbody.querySelectorAll("tr"))
            .sort(comparer(Array.prototype.slice.call(th.parentNode.children).indexOf(th), this.asc = !this.asc))
            .forEach(function(tr) {
                tbody.appendChild(tr)
            });
    })
});
```

Does anyone know a simple solution to my problem?