# <th> doesn't display CSS class when class assigned to <th> by Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using Nick Grealy's amazingly terse table sorter ([Sorting HTML table with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267781/sorting-html-table-with-javascript)), and trying to modify it to show a triangle to indicate which column is sorted.  I assign a class to the <th> in question, but the triangle doesn't appear.  Curiously, if I assign an ID to the  then I can get the triangle to appear, but if there's more than one table on the page, then multiple tables can't contain a <th> with the same ID, so only one table will show the sort triangle.

```js
const getCellValue = (tr, idx) => tr.children[idx].innerText || tr.children[idx].textContent;

const comparer = (idx, asc) => (a, b) => ((v1, v2) => 
    v1 !== '' && v2 !== '' && !isNaN(v1) && !isNaN(v2) ? v1 - v2 : v1.toString().localeCompare(v2)
    )(getCellValue(asc ? a : b, idx), getCellValue(asc ? b : a, idx));

// do the work...
oldTH = document; // Prime the th variable to avoid undefined error
document.querySelectorAll('th').forEach(th => th.addEventListener('click', (() => {
    oldTH.id = '';
    th.id = 'downArrow';
    th.class = 'downArrow';
    oldTH = th;
    const table = th.closest('table');
    Array.from(table.querySelectorAll('tr:nth-child(n+2)'))
        .sort(comparer(Array.from(th.parentNode.children).indexOf(th), this.asc = !this.asc))
        .forEach(tr => table.appendChild(tr) );
})));
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}
th {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#downArrow::after { content: '▼'; color: green; }
.downArrow::after { content: '▼'; color: green; }
```

```html
<table>
    <tr><th>Country</th><th>Date</th><th>Size</th></tr>
    <tr><td>France</td><td>2001-01-01</td><td><i>25</i></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href=#>spain</a></td><td><i>2005-05-05</i></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>Lebanon</b></td><td><a href=#>2002-02-02</a></td><td><b>-17</b></td></tr>
    <tr><td><i>Argentina</i></td><td>2005-04-04</td><td><a href=#>100</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>USA</td><td></td><td>-6</td></tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr><th>Country</th><th>Date</th><th>Size</th></tr>
    <tr><td>France</td><td>2001-01-01</td><td><i>25</i></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href=#>spain</a></td><td><i>2005-05-05</i></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The property is called `className` not `class`. [Element.className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className)

Comment: `class` is a reserved term in Javascript, hence it's `className`, not `class`. `th.className = 'downArrow';`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add a class using `th.class = ...`. However, you can use `th.className = ...` to set a class.

[MDN documentation on `className` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className)

```js
const getCellValue = (tr, idx) => tr.children[idx].innerText || tr.children[idx].textContent;

const comparer = (idx, asc) => (a, b) => ((v1, v2) => 
    v1 !== '' && v2 !== '' && !isNaN(v1) && !isNaN(v2) ? v1 - v2 : v1.toString().localeCompare(v2)
    )(getCellValue(asc ? a : b, idx), getCellValue(asc ? b : a, idx));

// do the work...
oldTH = document; // Prime the th variable to avoid undefined error
document.querySelectorAll('th').forEach(th => th.addEventListener('click', (() => {
    oldTH.className = undefined;
    th.className = 'downArrow';
    oldTH = th;
    const table = th.closest('table');
    Array.from(table.querySelectorAll('tr:nth-child(n+2)'))
        .sort(comparer(Array.from(th.parentNode.children).indexOf(th), this.asc = !this.asc))
        .forEach(tr => table.appendChild(tr) );
})));
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}
th {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.downArrow::after { content: '▼'; color: green; }
```

```html
<table>
    <tr><th>Country</th><th>Date</th><th>Size</th></tr>
    <tr><td>France</td><td>2001-01-01</td><td><i>25</i></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href=#>spain</a></td><td><i>2005-05-05</i></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>Lebanon</b></td><td><a href=#>2002-02-02</a></td><td><b>-17</b></td></tr>
    <tr><td><i>Argentina</i></td><td>2005-04-04</td><td><a href=#>100</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>USA</td><td></td><td>-6</td></tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr><th>Country</th><th>Date</th><th>Size</th></tr>
    <tr><td>France</td><td>2001-01-01</td><td><i>25</i></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href=#>spain</a></td><td><i>2005-05-05</i></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Class is a reserved keyword in JavaScript, and `th.class` is an invalid syntax. Instead of `th.class ='downArrow'`, use `th.setAttribute('class', 'downArrow')`, the primary way of setting attributes such as class, src etc.

Comment: A little explanation might be helpful.