# Sorting a HTML table with Array#sort

Tags: javascript, html

I know this site is a great resource that offers methods of sorting a HTML table by coding the sort and element swap myself. I use that, and it works fine. My goal is to NOT add an included library, but was imagining possibly a better method might be as follows:

Where tr = document.getElementById("table1").rows,
an element is accessed as tr[index].cells[0].textContent

So this tr looks as if it is an array of rows.

However

```js
tr = document.getElementById("table1").rows;  
tr.sort(function(a, b) {            
  return b.cells[0].textContent - a.cells[0].textContent;    //order high to low   
})
```

fails, because it says tr.sort is not a function.  And table.rows does seem defined as an Object instead of an Array.  Don't know how that differs, but rows looks and acts like an array.

Is there some workaround to allow this array method to work with Javascript sort?

Response to question in the comment:

Table is complicated because each row item is actually two adjacent rows. Plus a few TD are blank, causing numeric NaN errors unless handled.  I only sort first row of 2, but move two rows.  But I do have additional simple ordinary tables that could be sorted.   17 columns, one row looks like

```html
<tr><td><a href="https://www.morningstar.com/funds/xnas/vfiax/performance">VFIAX</a>
><td>5.47<td>-36.97<td>26.62<td>15.05<td>2.08<td>15.96<td>32.33<td>13.64<td>1.36<td>11.93<td>21.79<td>-4.43<td>31.46<td>18.37
><td>13.34<td><b>S&P 500 Index</b><td>
<tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
```

and my current code is

```js
function sortTable(tr, sort_col) {                              
  var len, i, x, y, a, b;   
  len = tr.length - 2;   
  i = 1;   
  while (i < len) {   
    for (i = 1; i < len; i += 2) {  //double rows for each item
      a = tr[i].cells[sort_col].textContent;   
      b = tr[i + 2].cells[sort_col].textContent;    //text for ticker in col 0   
      if (sort_col > 0) {   
        a = parseFloat(a); //parseFloat because it is reading string fields like 12.6%   
        b = parseFloat(b);   
        if (isNaN(a)) a = 0;    //early blank values cause NaN errors   
        if (isNaN(b)) b = 0;   
      }   
      if ( (sort_col == 0)? a > b : a < b) {   
        tr[i].parentNode.insertBefore(tr[i + 2], tr[i]);   
        tr[i+1].parentNode.insertBefore(tr[i + 3], tr[i + 1]);  //2nd of double rows   
        break;   
      }   
    } // i   
  }   
  Sorted = 1;   
}
```

Comment: Are your values in table hard-coded or are they filled in with javascript?

Comment: hard coded numbers

Comment: Can you provide HTML code of your `<table> .. </table>` ?

Comment: tried to add response in original post edit

Comment: Please review this help post on [formatting within StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Array.from` to get the `td` elements in an array that can be sorted. Then add each of them again to the table in that order. This will be understood as a *move* in the DOM, so you'll end up with sorted table rows:

```js
let table = document.getElementById("table1");
let trs = table.rows;

Array.from(trs)
     .sort((a, b) => a.cells[0].textContent - b.cells[0].textContent)
     .forEach(tr => table.appendChild(tr));
```

```html
<table id="table1">
   <tr><td>2</td></tr>
   <tr><td>4</td></tr>
   <tr><td>3</td></tr>
   <tr><td>1</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is wonderfully elegant. I created a giant block of code to solve this and learned alot from your answer. THanks

Comment: I'm not the OP. Just an appreciative bystander.

Comment: Thank you.  I checked it, and it does the job and is quite elegant, but for a huge table, I worry about the additional run effort of building another table and then moving it back.  Not sure that work improves the bubble sort.

Comment: It is not building another table though. `Array.from` is only creating a shallow copy of the DOM object (`tr`) references. Secondly, JavaScript engines will most often *not* use bubble sort, but one of the more efficient ones, like merge sort, quick sort, ...etc.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I hoped to use the Javascript sort, because the examples found to code sorting a table use their own bubble sort.  Probably it only matters much for a very large sort.  Your syntax is new to me, but the .cells[0] does clearly imply one array index for each table row, so I am liking that. I understand x.sort()  and assume the two blank indented dots must refer to Array.  So I think you're right, but that's still new for me, still trying to find that described to be sure I understand it.

Comment: Would you mind enhancing with a heading (`th`) row (`tr`) and multiple columns per detail  (`td`) row (`tr`)?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, if you cannot make it work, feel free to post a question.

Comment: @trincot Thank you for the offer. I found a solution that sorts on any column a-z then z-a based on click on column header: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49041392/6929343

Comment: Good to hear you found what you needed!

Answer (score 0):

This is NOT another answer, but just lengthy comments on trincots wonderful solution.  I had a 100 row table with sorting, but it had one option where each row element became two rows which had to sort together.  So for the double rows, I created a BubbleSort routine.   But it finally dawned on me how to use trincots solution (and I also kept the Bubblesort only for the two row case).

The timing varies a bit each time, but it's several times faster, 5 to 8x.  I also had the header issue (both top and repeated bottom header), and a lower case alpha case, so had to modify it a bit. In case it may be of interest, this is what I figured out.  It does work well. I'm no expert, so I'd appreciate hearing about any errors or efficiency improvements.   Thank you trincot

```
//trincot's original, which is wonderful
let table = document.getElementById("table1");
let trs = table.rows;
Array.from(trs)
     .sort((a, b) => a.cells[0].textContent - b.cells[0].textContent)
     .forEach(tr => table.appendChild(tr));


//My HTML   (I already had the tbl and trs var)
//let t1 = performance.now();
        if (optn_row_spacing == 1) {    //if only single rows in table vs. two rows per element
            Array.from(trs)
              .sort((a, b) => JavaScriptSort(a, b))     //call comparison function
              .forEach(tr => tbl.appendChild(tr));
        }
        else BubbleSortTable(trs, ifBinary, );      //two row elements, which can be binary or alpha columns
//console.log("Sort " + optn_row_spacing + " took " +  (performance.now() - t1) + " milliseconds. Span Btn " + spn + ". Optn Btn " + btn);


//Javascript sort function for a, b comparison
function  JavaScriptSort(a, b) {    // if single rows, so elements are NOT double row groups
    if (a.rowIndex == 0 || b.rowIndex == bottom_header_row)     //leave both headers in place
        return 0;       //needed row number to recognize headers
    var a2 = a.cells[sort_btn_col].textContent,
        b2 = b.cells[sort_btn_col].textContent;
                                    //sort_btn_col is global access
    if (sort_btn_col == 0)          //col 0 & 12 are text
        return a2 > b2;             //0 IS ALL UPPER CASE TEXT
    if (sort_btn_col == 12)         //12 is Mixed Case which didn't sort right
        return a2.toLowerCase() > b2.toLowerCase();
    //else numeric.. The parseFloat because it's reading fields ending with "%"
    return parseFloat(b2) - parseFloat(a2);     //decreasing size
}
```