# Datatype agnostic sorting HTML table with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dataframe, sorting, flask

There is old post on Stack Overflow with an excellent sorting solution for any tables ([Sorting HTML table with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267781/sorting-html-table-with-javascript) - answer provided by Nick Grealy and fixed by jedwards (first row sorting issue)).

What I love about this, it doesn't require passing function to column headers in html or assigning classes to html elements. This makes it work seamlessly with Flask and pandas DataFrames.

Solution as follow (credit Nick Grealy, jedwards):

```
const getCellValue = (tr, idx) => tr.children[idx].innerText || tr.children[idx].textContent;

const comparer = (idx, asc) => (a, b) => ((v1, v2) => 
    v1 !== '' && v2 !== '' && !isNaN(v1) && !isNaN(v2) ? v1 - v2 : v1.toString().localeCompare(v2)
    )(getCellValue(asc ? a : b, idx), getCellValue(asc ? b : a, idx));

// do the work...
document.querySelectorAll('th').forEach(th => th.addEventListener('click', (() => {
    const table = th.closest('table');
    const tbody = table.querySelector('tbody');
    Array.from(tbody.querySelectorAll('tr'))
      .sort(comparer(Array.from(th.parentNode.children).indexOf(th), this.asc = !this.asc))
      .forEach(tr => tbody.appendChild(tr) );
})));
```

Problem arise when table contains numbers as strings. For example when user wants to control format of the cell values in Python (where table/dataframe is created) and uses formatters to do it example below:

```
# part of the function building dataframe and taking aruments inlcuding
# html   ==> True/False -> return pandas df or df.to_html
# classes ==> 'my-css-class' -> assign CSS classes
df = pd.DataFrame(sliced_view_df.to_dict()) #Clears up issue with formatters for panda <1.2

if html:
    ff_pct3 = lambda x: '{0:.3f}%'.format(x*100)
    ff_date = lambda x: x.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
    fmtr = {
                    'my_number1':            ff_pct3,
                    'my_number2':            ff_pct3,
                    'Start Date':            ff_date,
                    'End Date':              ff_date,                
                }
    
    return df.to_html(formatters=fmtr, classes=classes)

else:
    return df
```

I've fixed JavaScript sorting function for floats passes as string, by converting them to float using parseFloat. I've replacing this line:

```
(getCellValue(asc ? a : b, idx), getCellValue(asc ? b : a, idx))
```

with this line:

```
(parseFloat(getCellValue(asc ? a : b, idx)), parseFloat(getCellValue(asc ? b : a, idx))
```

But this won't work for columns containing strings or dates as parseFloat will return array of NaN, which cannot be sorted.

I'm new to JavaScript and I couldn't solve datatype issue in this script myself.

I know there are more robust solutions like table sorter (https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#Demo). But I love how clean and concise is the JavaScript sorting solution above. Maybe there is also a clean way to make it work for other data types (including numbers as strings)?

Comment: The reason more robust scripts like tablesorter exist is because simple case code that you like isn't robust enough for more complex case variations. You can try enhancing it but then there are many edge cases you may not have considered that something that has been around for much longer has likely uncovered and resolved. Sometimes you can fix a car with just a screw driver and a  hammer, most of the time you need far more specialized tools

Comment: True, I probably got to involved in fixing it. I was thinking about just 3 options (string, date as string, float as string), thus I've tried (and failed) to do 2 checks - checks 1. If string is a date and then converting date to a number 2. If string is float and then parseFloat before sorting it.