# Is there a way I can make a HTML table sortable when exported from an Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: html, excel, sorting, html-table, ms-office

For clarity, the spreadsheet in question is a repertoire list of all the songs that my cover band performs, with hyperlinks to lyrics and chords. I can sort it just fine in Excel, but not when it's exported to HTML.

I have started exporting it as HTML as that is slightly more accessible when live on stage. However, it would be beneficial to be able to sort the list by different attributes like genre, artist, year, etc.

As far as I can tell, there is no way for me to sort the data in the HTML table directly. In order to re-sort the data, I have to open Excel, sort the table, and re-save / re-publish it as a webpage.

I tried this extension called [Tabulazer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabulazer-table-filter-an/ikfbkffbgkdghhnjfoomdkeifljlepah) but it didn't seem to work.

As I'm only an amateur programmer, I'm not sure how I would go about solving this problem. I would guess it probably has something to do with the `thead` table header tag.

Comment: Perhaps some added javascript? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267781/sorting-html-table-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, Tabulazer is only available as a web browser extension. Your visitors hence have to install it first before sorting out the tables.

If you're not keen enough with good old JavaScript frameworks like JQuery and JQuery UI, it's okay. There's [a simple example from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table#sorting_rows_with_a_click_on_the_th_element) that lets you sort tables by clicking the `<th>` (table heading) cells.