# Sorting table and displaying sorting symbols

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

I stumbled upon Nick Grealy's answer to a question on here about sorting tables (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49041392), with jedwards fix for people having rows inside a tbody (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53880407). It was a nice piece of code, which worked perfectly for what I wanted it for.

I am just having a hard time implementing sorting symbols in the th headers of the table for when the table is sorted ascending or descending for a specific column. I came up with this which works somewhat okay:

```js
const getCellValue = (tr, idx) => tr.children[idx].innerText || tr.children[idx].textContent;
const comparer = (idx, asc) => (a, b) => ((v1, v2) => 
    v1 !== '' && v2 !== '' && !isNaN(v1) && !isNaN(v2) ? v1 - v2 : v1.toString().localeCompare(v2)
    )(getCellValue(asc ? a : b, idx), getCellValue(asc ? b : a, idx));
document.querySelectorAll('th').forEach(th => th.addEventListener('click', ((e) => { //own code: added "e" to use further down
    const table = th.closest('table');
    const tbody = table.querySelector('tbody');
    let buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button"); //getting all button tags
    const arrayButtons = ['0', '1', '2']; //own code: for use further down, as I have 3 buttons
    Array.from(tbody.querySelectorAll('tr'))
        .sort(comparer(Array.from(th.parentNode.children).indexOf(th), this.asc = !this.asc))
        .forEach(tr => tbody.appendChild(tr));
    arrayButtons.forEach(e => buttons[e].setAttribute("data-dir", "")); //own code: reset all data-dir fields in buttons
    if (this.asc) { //own code: if ascending, fill in asc in data-dir field in button, else data-dir desc gets filled in.
        e.target.setAttribute("data-dir", "asc");
    } else {
        e.target.setAttribute("data-dir", "desc");
    }
})));
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font: inherit;
  color:inherit;
  width: 100%;
}
th button[data-dir="asc"]::after {
  content: " " url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 13 13' xml:space='preserve' width='13' height='13' transform='scale(1 -1)'%3E%3Cpath d='M2.039 5.171c.114.114.25.172.406.172h8.107a.55.55 0 0 0 .406-.172c.114-.114.172-.25.172-.406s-.057-.292-.172-.406L6.906.302C6.792.187 6.658.13 6.5.13s-.292.057-.406.172L2.039 4.355a.557.557 0 0 0-.172.406.541.541 0 0 0 .172.408zM6.5 12.473a.163.163 0 0 1-.127-.055L2.319 8.364a.159.159 0 0 1-.055-.127c0-.042.01-.081.055-.127s.084-.055.127-.055h8.107c.042 0 .081.01.127.055s.055.084.055.127a.163.163 0 0 1-.055.127l-4.052 4.054c-.047.045-.084.055-.127.055m0 .396a.55.55 0 0 0 .406-.172l4.054-4.054a.557.557 0 0 0 .172-.406.549.549 0 0 0-.172-.406.557.557 0 0 0-.406-.172H2.447a.549.549 0 0 0-.406.172.557.557 0 0 0-.172.406.55.55 0 0 0 .172.406l4.054 4.053c.114.114.25.172.406.172z' fill='%23000'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
th button[data-dir="desc"]::after {
  content: " " url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 13 13' xml:space='preserve' width='13' height='13'%3E%3Cpath d='M2.039 5.171c.114.114.25.172.406.172h8.107a.55.55 0 0 0 .406-.172c.114-.114.172-.25.172-.406s-.057-.292-.172-.406L6.906.302C6.792.187 6.658.13 6.5.13s-.292.057-.406.172L2.039 4.355a.557.557 0 0 0-.172.406.541.541 0 0 0 .172.408zM6.5 12.473a.163.163 0 0 1-.127-.055L2.319 8.364a.159.159 0 0 1-.055-.127c0-.042.01-.081.055-.127s.084-.055.127-.055h8.107c.042 0 .081.01.127.055s.055.084.055.127a.163.163 0 0 1-.055.127l-4.052 4.054c-.047.045-.084.055-.127.055m0 .396a.55.55 0 0 0 .406-.172l4.054-4.054a.557.557 0 0 0 .172-.406.549.549 0 0 0-.172-.406.557.557 0 0 0-.406-.172H2.447a.549.549 0 0 0-.406.172.557.557 0 0 0-.172.406.55.55 0 0 0 .172.406l4.054 4.053c.114.114.25.172.406.172z' fill='%23000'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

```html
<table width='100%'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th width='20%'>Image</th>
<th width='20%'><button data-dir=''>Number</button></th>
<th width='40%'><button data-dir=''>Name</button></th>
<th width='20%'><button data-dir=''>Postal code</button></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>IMG1</td>
<td>xxx</td>
<td>John Johnson</td>
<td>56430</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>IMG2</td>
<td>yyy</td>
<td>Sally Johnson</td>
<td>56430</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

There are some problems with the code that I can't seem to solve, and which I am asking for help to fix:

1. When I click the th-header of the image-column, it sets the data-dir of the th and removes the data-dir from all the other columns and basically starts sorting the image-column. The image-column does not have a button and is not supposed to be able to trigger the sorting function or the data-dir function. Any way to fix this?
2. When a table is already sorted ascending, for example the Name-column, when clicking the th-header for the name-column, it sorts it ascending first (even though it already is) and then on second-click descending, instead of descending right away. Any way to fix this?
3. Is the code optimized as it is, especially the parts I have added with the let buttons, const arrayButtons and the if else for setAttribute of data-dir? Could it be more optimized?

I am trying to learn, so any feedback would be appreciated. :)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working version, there were a couple of problems.
It was sorting even the **Image** column because you've used `document.querySelectorAll('th')` and added a click listener on all those elements instead of doing that for the `<button>` elements.

Your version doesn't remember the previous sorting direction because you've used `this.asc` which is a *global* variable not something associated with the specific column.
To fix that, I've used `button.dataset.prevDir` to keep track of the previous direction without always showing the arrows.

As for the optimisation. No `arrayButtons` is not the way to go.
In my example I've used `buttons` which is a list of all the buttons and instead of `setAttribute`, I've used `dataset`.

```js
const getCellValue = (tr, idx) => tr.children[idx].innerText || tr.children[idx].textContent;
const comparer = (idx, asc) => (a, b) => ((v1, v2) => 
    v1 !== '' && v2 !== '' && !isNaN(v1) && !isNaN(v2) ? v1 - v2 : v1.toString().localeCompare(v2)
    )(getCellValue(asc ? a : b, idx), getCellValue(asc ? b : a, idx));
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
buttons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', ((e) => {
    const th = button.parentNode;
    const table = th.closest('table');
    const tbody = table.querySelector('tbody');
    button.dataset.prevDir = button.dataset.prevDir === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc';
    buttons.forEach((btn) => (btn.dataset.dir = ''));
    Array.from(tbody.querySelectorAll('tr'))
        .sort(comparer(Array.from(th.parentNode.children).indexOf(th), button.dataset.prevDir === 'asc'))
        .forEach(tr => tbody.appendChild(tr));
    button.dataset.dir = button.dataset.prevDir;
})));
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font: inherit;
  color:inherit;
  width: 100%;
}
th button[data-dir="asc"]::after {
  content: " " url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 13 13' xml:space='preserve' width='13' height='13' transform='scale(1 -1)'%3E%3Cpath d='M2.039 5.171c.114.114.25.172.406.172h8.107a.55.55 0 0 0 .406-.172c.114-.114.172-.25.172-.406s-.057-.292-.172-.406L6.906.302C6.792.187 6.658.13 6.5.13s-.292.057-.406.172L2.039 4.355a.557.557 0 0 0-.172.406.541.541 0 0 0 .172.408zM6.5 12.473a.163.163 0 0 1-.127-.055L2.319 8.364a.159.159 0 0 1-.055-.127c0-.042.01-.081.055-.127s.084-.055.127-.055h8.107c.042 0 .081.01.127.055s.055.084.055.127a.163.163 0 0 1-.055.127l-4.052 4.054c-.047.045-.084.055-.127.055m0 .396a.55.55 0 0 0 .406-.172l4.054-4.054a.557.557 0 0 0 .172-.406.549.549 0 0 0-.172-.406.557.557 0 0 0-.406-.172H2.447a.549.549 0 0 0-.406.172.557.557 0 0 0-.172.406.55.55 0 0 0 .172.406l4.054 4.053c.114.114.25.172.406.172z' fill='%23000'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
th button[data-dir="desc"]::after {
  content: " " url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 13 13' xml:space='preserve' width='13' height='13'%3E%3Cpath d='M2.039 5.171c.114.114.25.172.406.172h8.107a.55.55 0 0 0 .406-.172c.114-.114.172-.25.172-.406s-.057-.292-.172-.406L6.906.302C6.792.187 6.658.13 6.5.13s-.292.057-.406.172L2.039 4.355a.557.557 0 0 0-.172.406.541.541 0 0 0 .172.408zM6.5 12.473a.163.163 0 0 1-.127-.055L2.319 8.364a.159.159 0 0 1-.055-.127c0-.042.01-.081.055-.127s.084-.055.127-.055h8.107c.042 0 .081.01.127.055s.055.084.055.127a.163.163 0 0 1-.055.127l-4.052 4.054c-.047.045-.084.055-.127.055m0 .396a.55.55 0 0 0 .406-.172l4.054-4.054a.557.557 0 0 0 .172-.406.549.549 0 0 0-.172-.406.557.557 0 0 0-.406-.172H2.447a.549.549 0 0 0-.406.172.557.557 0 0 0-.172.406.55.55 0 0 0 .172.406l4.054 4.053c.114.114.25.172.406.172z' fill='%23000'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

```html
<table width='100%'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th width='20%'>Image</th>
<th width='20%'><button data-dir=''>Number</button></th>
<th width='40%'><button data-dir=''>Name</button></th>
<th width='20%'><button data-dir=''>Postal code</button></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>IMG1</td>
<td>xxx</td>
<td>John Johnson</td>
<td>56430</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>IMG2</td>
<td>yyy</td>
<td>Sally Johnson</td>
<td>56430</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow, okay I learned something! Thanks for this great answer and the explanation - this works beautifully. And I guess if I know that the number-column and the postal-column would already be ordered by ascending order in the table from the beginning, I could add "data-prev-dir='asc'" to both of those buttons, right? With the name-column, I can't predict whether the column is already sorted ascending or descending (or randomly sorted) from the beginning, so that should be left alone I guess.

Comment: @AnonymousJ Yes, if you want to set a default value, you need to use `data-prev-dir` instead of `data-dir`.

Answer (score -1):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Column from "./Column";
import Row from "./Row";
import getSortedData from "./getSortedData";

import "./styles.css";

const data = [
  { name: "Manu", score: 98, age: 21 },
  { name: "Fran", score: 70, age: 43 },
  { name: "Jose", score: 22, age: 22 },
  { name: "Ana", score: 23, age: 99 },
  { name: "Luis", score: 33, age: 14 },
  { name: "Simon", score: 47, age: 54 },
  { name: "Xavier", score: 44, age: 35 }
];

export default function App() {
  const [sortedBy, setSortedBy] = useState(null);
  const [direction, setDirection] = useState("UP");

  const onSortBy = name => {
    if (sortedBy !== name) {
      setSortedBy(name);
    } else if (direction === "UP") {
      setDirection("DOWN");
    } else {
      setSortedBy(null);
      setDirection("UP");
    }
  };

  const sortedData = getSortedData(data, sortedBy, direction);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <Column
            name="name"
            direction={direction}
            sortedBy={sortedBy}
            onSortBy={onSortBy}
          />
          <Column
            name="score"
            direction={direction}
            sortedBy={sortedBy}
            onSortBy={onSortBy}
          />
          <Column
            name="age"
            direction={direction}
            sortedBy={sortedBy}
            onSortBy={onSortBy}
          />
        </tr>
        {sortedData.map(player => (
          <Row player={player} />
        ))}
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Just posting code of something similar without explanation is not very helpfull

Comment: btw, it looks like op want not to use libraries.