# HTML Table Sorting in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have simple HTML Table, I need to add sorting and grouping on every columns in jQuery.

```
<table cellspacing='0'>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Task Details</th>
        <th>Progress</th>
        <th>Vital Task</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Create pretty table design</td>
        <td>100%</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
```

Comment: awesome. I need stuff too sometimes. But what have you tried?

Comment: What are you trying to say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various plugins to perform this using jQuery. The most known one is jQuery tablesorter:

http://tablesorter.com/docs/

There are loads of such plugins here, pick the one you like most:

http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2013/06/jquery-filter-sort-plugins.html

Comment: Can any one give me code for this, no plugin.

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160277/jquery-table-sort - however, it didn't work for me - the table isn't sortable. Why don't you want to use a plugin?

Comment: i want to use int within my own plugin..

Comment: Check the code of these plugins and adapt it to your own one. Or, you can simply make a requirement in your plugin that it needs another plugin in order to work (like jQuery UI needs jQuery, for example)

Answer (score 4):

You could use [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) for this. It's very simple to use.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $("#myTable").tablesorter();  // <-- 'myTable' is the id of your table    
});
```

[Here](http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo) you could check a working demo

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using [datatables](http://www.datatables.net/), you use it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#example').dataTable();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not reinvent the wheel. Use [jquery tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) plugin.