# How to sort lists with text input value?

Tags: jquery, html, sorting, filter

My HTML is a list as bellow:

```
<ul class="friend_list">
    <li> 
        <a href="#">Krishna</a>
        <a href="#">Karan</a>
        <a href="#">Ram</a>
        <a href="#">Hari</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<input type="text" name="sort" value="Search" id="sort">
```

Here when a user enters any string in the input text `#sort` it should sort the value list according to match. Like if I enter `K` in the input `Krishna` and `Karan` list should show and `Hari` should hide. And again When I enter `H` or `Hari`, the `Hari` `li` should display and others should hide.

`#sort` key up function should filter result as the SQL `LIKE` Operator does.

Can anyone help me find a solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery table sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160277/jquery-table-sort)

Comment: do you want it only with the first letter of the name? or should it be like `letter%` or `%letter%`. And is it a requirement that it is only one letter?

Comment: This isn't so much of a sort as you're hiding non relevant items. It's a filter.

Comment: i want %letter% @Spokey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an idea:

```
 $("#sort").keyup(function(){
      var v = $(this).val();
      if(v.length==0)
      {    $("a").show();}
      else
      {
      $("a").each(function(){
          if($(this).text().indexOf(v)==0)
              $(this).show();
          else
              $(this).hide();
      })
      }
  }) ;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fqyCM/

Change

```
if($(this).text().indexOf(v)==0)
```

to

```
if($(this).text().indexOf(v)!=-1)
```

to change from starts with to contains

Answer (score 0):

you do not provide any code, I doubt anyone is going to do it for you. Here is a code that might give you what you want :
http://codecanyon.net/item/advanced-tables/full_screen_preview/53366?ref=lvraa
I'd recommand you use a jQuery plugin for this if you not very experimented with programming.