# Inserting rows into table which rows are sorted by some value attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple HTML table and I want to insert new rows to the table with JQuery.

Each row has a custom `val` attribute with UNIX timestamp inside, for example:

```
<tr data-val="1356998400"><!-- Some row content --></tr>
```

I want to insert new rows with JQuery, and I want them to be sorted by `val` attribute after insertion.

The obviuos solution is to set `id`-s to rows and manually scan the rows array (performing time values comparison) before every single insertion to find the correct place to insert, but may be there is more JQuery-like solution? I guess a kind of one-line solution should exist for this case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery table sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160277/jquery-table-sort)

Comment: The val attribute is not valid. If your webpage is HTML 5 a valid attribute would be data-val

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initially, you could sort the table with a basic `sort` function (if the rows haven't been sorted already):

#### Markup

(Note: Added your custom `val` attribute as a data attribute)

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-val="1"><td>1st</td></tr>
    <tr data-val="4"><td>3rd</td></tr>
    <tr data-val="7"><td>4th</td></tr>
    <tr data-val="2"><td>2nd</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

#### jQuery

```
$('table').html(function() {
  return $(this).find('tr').sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).data('val') > $(b).data('val');
  });
});
```

Once the rows have been sorted, you can easily find the position to insert the new row by grabbing the first row where its `data-val` is greater or equal to the `data-val` of the `newRow`:

```
var $newRow = $('<tr data-val="3"><td>Between 2nd and 3rd!</td></tr>');
var elementToInsertBefore = $('tr').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('val') >= $newRow.data('val');
}).get(0);

if (typeof elementToInsertBefore === 'undefined') {
    $('table').append($newRow);  
} else {
    $newRow.insertBefore(elementToInsertBefore);
}
```

So, if the filter doesn't return an `elementToInsertBefore` (ie. there were no existing rows with a `data-val` greater, or equal to the `$newRow's` `data-val`, append it to the end of the table, otherwise insert it before the `elementToInsertBefore`.

**Side Note:** It'd probably be more efficient to use a `for` loop to get the `elementToInsertBefore`. That way, as soon as you find a row which meets the criteria, you can `break` out, which prevents further unecessary iterations (which *could* have a decent performance gain when dealing with a large number of rows).

If you want something more elaborate, have a look at the jQuery plugins mentioned.

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YtNPm/15/)

Comment: Awesome! this is what I was searching for! But it is not actually correct. New item should between first and second element, not between second and third.

Comment: @zavg `$newRow` has `data-val="3"`, 2nd and 3rd have `data-val's` of `2` and `4`, respectively, so it's inserting at the correct position, unless I misunderstood something?

Comment: The fiddle code was changed a little since the time I posted the comment, but now it is absolutely correct. The second JS-snippet in your answer is exactly what I was searching for!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution: Fetch all tr elements with http://api.jquery.com/children/ (no Ids necessary) check the values and rearrange them. If they are in the right order, delete your table content and reinsert your rows.

(Isn't even necessary to clear your table and reinsert all rows. http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/ enables you to insert a row between the correct two values if you code the right loop logic)

You can fetch all kind of attributes from your dom nodes by using http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 0):

i have a fork of [tablesorter](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/index.html) that allows you to write a parser that can [extract data attributes](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers-advanced.html) from the table cell as well as assign specific [textExtraction for each column](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-option-text-extraction.html).

Code :

```
$(function(){

  $.tablesorter.addParser({ 
    // set a unique id 
    id: 'myParser', 
    is: function(s) { 
      // return false so this parser is not auto detected 
      return false; 
    }, 
    format: function(s, table, cell, cellIndex) { 
      // get data attributes from $(cell).attr('data-something');
      // check specific column using cellIndex
      return $(cell).attr('data-something');
    }, 
    // set type, either numeric or text 
    type: 'text' 
  }); 

  $('table').tablesorter({ 
    headers : { 
      0 : { sorter: 'myParser' }
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with JQuery then there could be n no. of options Like

tablesorter, JQuery Datatable,etc.

Just see the following example.

http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort based on `val` attribute value on each `<tr>`, you can use the following code.

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/RvJ6e/

**HTML Code**

```
<table>
</table>
```

**CSS Code**

```
table td {
    border : 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
$(function() {
    //To add a new row after every 3 seconds.
    setInterval(function() {
        //I am generating a random number to demo table sorting properly.
        var val = parseInt(Math.random() * 10000);
        $('table').append('<tr val="' + val + '"><td>' + val + '</td></tr>');
        sortTable();
    }, 3000);
});

function compareRows (tr1, tr2) {
    var val1 = parseInt($(tr1).attr('val'));
    var val2 = parseInt($(tr2).attr('val'));
    return ((val1 > val2) ? 1 : ((val1 < val2) ? -1 : 0));
};

function sortTable() {
    $('table tr').sort(compareRows).appendTo('table');
}
```

I took many assumptions. Need to update as per your requirement.

If you want advanced level of sorting then as suggested by others, its better to depend on some jQuery plug-ins available.

Answer (score 0):

to sort an entire table according to the `val` attribute in the `tr` elements you may use the follwing code:

```
orig  = 
    $.map (
        $("tr[val]")
        , function( e, idx ) {
            return "<tr val='"+$(e).attr('val')+"'>" + $(e).html() + "</tr>";
          }
    );
sorted = orig.sort();
$("tbody").replaceWith(sorted);
```

this method is viable if your inserts are a bulk operation. if you need a sorted table immediately after insertion of individual elements you will need some bisection search on the array of `tr` elements.

have a look at the [sample page](http://collapsar.ohost.de/data/so.18103035.inserting-rows-into-table-which-rows-are-sorted-by-some-value-attribute.html).