# how to call jquery .on method in data table sorting

Tags: jquery, html

May be this question is asked before but i am stuck in a position where i am able to sort my data table at the time of page loading.But when i replace the whole table with data populated by ajax then it stops working.Please help me.

i am using the following code according to [jQuery table sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160277/jquery-table-sort)

```
$('#loc_sort, #rate_sort')  // these are the th ids that i want to sort
.wrapInner('<span title="sort this column"/>')
.each(function(){       
    var th = $(this),
        thIndex = th.index(),
        inverse = false;

    th.click(function(){

        table.find('td').filter(function(){

            return $(this).index() === thIndex;

        }).sortElements(function(a, b){

            return $.text([a]) > $.text([b]) ?
                inverse ? -1 : 1
                : inverse ? 1 : -1;

        }, function(){

            // parentNode is the element we want to move
            return this.parentNode; 

        });

        inverse = !inverse;

    });

});
```

please tell me how can i use this code with .on method.I append the html code that coming from ajax to

```
<div id="outer_all_div"></div>
```

div.Which is not replacing.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Simply bind your event to the parent.  Then it only needs to be bound once and it won't get lost when you replace the inner table.

```
$('#outer_all_div').on('click', '#loc_sort, #rate_sort', function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: yes this should work but first time its sorting the data but from second time its not working.

Comment: Show us your code using the "on" function and we can further debug.