# Sort rows in css table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a css table and need to be able to sort the rows by clicking on headers. All the plugins I've found so far require an actual table. Are there any jquery plugins that will allow to sort any html?

My data is structured like this:

```
<div class="data">
   <a href="">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
      <div>Three</div>
   </a>
</div>

.data { display: table;}
.data > a {display: table-row}
.data > a > div {display: table-cell}
```

Comment: Yes, there are jquery plugins for this. Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160277/jquery-table-sort

Comment: sorts anything => http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/