# jQuery: sort the results of find

Tags: jquery, sorting

I'd like to sort the result of find according to the name of the `input` as follows:

HTML:

```
<form id="sort" ...>
<input name=...>
<input name=...>
...
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
var result = $('#sort').find('input');
var serialized = result.sort(comparer(result)).serialize();

function comparer(index) {
  return function(a, b) {
    var valA = getCellValue(a, index);
    var valB = getCellValue(b, index);
    return valA.localeCompare(valB);
  };
};

function getCellValue(element, index) {
  return element.attr('name');
};
```

It doesn't work; error message: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` on the line: `return valA.localeCompare(valB);`

The above was from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160277/jquery-table-sort), but I don't quite understand the comparer function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `a` and `b` are plain DOM elements, not jQuery instancies so they don't have `attr` method. Here is the fixed code that doesn't rely on jQuery, as you can get DOM element property using bracket notation:

```
var result = $('#sort').find('input');
var serialized = result.sort(comparer('name')).serialize();

function comparer(index) {
  return function(a, b) {
    var valA = getCellValue(a, index);
    var valB = getCellValue(b, index);
    return valA.localeCompare(valB);
  };
};

function getCellValue(element, index) {
  return element[index];
};
```

Check the demo below.

```js
var result = $('#sort').find('input');
var serialized = result.sort(comparer('name')).serialize();

alert(serialized);

function comparer(index) {
  return function(a, b) {
    var valA = getCellValue(a, index);
    var valB = getCellValue(b, index);
    return valA.localeCompare(valB);
  };
};

function getCellValue(element, index) {
  return element[index];
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="sort">
    <input name="username" value="Thomas">
    <input name="age" value="12">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cwf7bcjy/1/) here. I used a function expression to define the comparer.

Basically if your form looks something like this:

```
<div id="sort">
<form>
    <input type="text" name="two" />
    <input type="text" name="one" />
</form>
</div>
```

Then the following javascript should sort the input elements by name and then serialize them:

```
var sorted = $('#sort').find('input');
var serialized = sorted.sort(function(a, b) { 
    var valA = getCellValue(a);
    var valB = getCellValue(b);
    return valA.localeCompare(valB);
}).serialize();
alert(serialized);

function getCellValue(element) {
  return element.name;
};
```

Or, if you prefer to use a named function, the following should work:

```
var sorted = $('#sort').find('input');
var serialized = sorted.sort(myComparer).serialize();
alert(serialized);

function myComparer(a, b) {
    var valA = getCellValue(a);
    var valB = getCellValue(b);
    return valA.localeCompare(valB);
}

function getCellValue(element) {
  return element.name;
};
```