# Table column index with previous rowspan columns

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have the following jsfiddle ready to show you my problem

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/rwurzer/no4sefyu/`
```

[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rwurzer/no4sefyu/)

Basically the problem I have is a table column where I have rowspan assigned to.

I want to get the right column index.

I hope my fiddle is good enough to explain my problem :-)

Hope anyone can help?

Comment: Sorry, too dumb to create a link to jsfiddle -.-

Comment: ID's must be **unique**!

Comment: Yeah, u r right, but that's not the problem at all. The click handle works fine with just one ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I know that you've already got an answer by try this variant. It's based on calculating indexes and should work for any cell. And I've removed duplicate `id` attributes in jsFiddle.

```
$('td').click(function(){
    var clickedEl = $(this);
    var myCol = clickedEl.closest("td").index();
    var myRow = clickedEl.closest("tr").index();
    var rowspans = $("td[rowspan]");
    rowspans.each(function () {
        var rs = $(this);
        var rsIndex = rs.closest("tr").index();
        var rsQuantity = parseInt(rs.attr("rowspan"));
        if (myRow > rsIndex && myRow <= rsIndex + rsQuantity - 1) {
            myCol++;
        }
    });
    alert('Row: ' + myRow + ', Column: ' + myCol);
});
```

Here is a demo in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/no4sefyu/4/). Just want to solve your problem with this approach =).

Answer (score 4):

This answer improves on Andrew's post by fixing issues with colspans, rowspans and problems if multiple tables are on the page.  I tested with lots of rowspan and colspan configurations.

```
//Takes a td/th or any element within and returns the row and column index of the cell taking into account rowspans and colspans
var getTableCellIndexes = function (elm) {
    var td = $(elm).closest("td,th");
    var col = 0;
    td.prevAll().each(function () { col += $(this).prop('colspan'); });
    var row = td.closest("tr").index();
    var tbody = td.closest('thead,tbody,tfoot');
    var rowspans = tbody.find("td[rowspan],th[rowspan]");
    rowspans.each(function () {
        var rs = $(this);
        var rsIndex = rs.closest("tr").index();
        var rsQuantity = rs.prop("rowspan");
        if (row > rsIndex && row <= rsIndex + rsQuantity - 1) {
            var rsCol = 0;
            rs.prevAll().each(function () { rsCol += $(this).prop('colspan'); });
            if (rsCol <= col) col += rs.prop('colspan');
        }
    });
    return { row: row, col: col };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

make changes -> 
`var myCol = $(this).closest("td").index();` replace with `var myCol = $(this).closest("td").html();` and you cannot have same id for all elements so make `nochKeinTermin` change it from id to class
Finally...

```
<table name="kalender" class="kalender" id="mytable" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="10">
    <tr>
        <td class="hiddenCell">&nbsp;</td>    
        <td class="hiddenCell" colspan="8">8</td>           
    </tr>                                      
    <tr>   
         <td>Uhrzeit</td>
         <td colspan="8" id="1440367200" class="rightBorder day">Montag, 24.08.2015</td>      
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="uhrzeit">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="120px" id="mitarbeiter_1">AnBi</td>
        <td width="120px" id="mitarbeiter_2">HeBi</td>
        <td width="120px" id="mitarbeiter_3">JuHa</td>
        <td width="120px" id="mitarbeiter_4">StRi</td>
        <td width="120px" id="mitarbeiter_5">FrWi</td>
        <td width="120px" id="mitarbeiter_7">EvSc</td>
        <td width="120px" id="mitarbeiter_8">JoAr</td>
        <td width="200px" class="rightBorder" id="mitarbeiter_10">GaHa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>  
        <td id="21600" class="uhrzeit">7:00</td>
        <td rowspan="2" class="terminActiveDoppel" id="11"  title="Patient">1</td>
        <td class="termin droppable nochKeinTermin" style="background:red;">2</td>
        <td class="termin droppable nochKeinTermin">3</td>
        <td class="termin droppable nochKeinTermin">4</td>
        <td class="termin droppable nochKeinTermin">5</td>
        <td class="termin droppable nochKeinTermin">6</td>
        <td class="termin droppable nochKeinTermin">7</td>
        <td class="terminRightBorder droppable nochKeinTermin">8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>  
        <td id="21600" class="uhrzeit">7:00</td>
        <td class="termin droppable nochKeinTermin" style="background:blue;">2</td>
        <td class="termin droppable nochKeinTermin">3</td>
        <td class="termin droppable nochKeinTermin">4</td>
        <td class="termin droppable nochKeinTermin">5</td>
        <td class="termin droppable nochKeinTermin">6</td>
        <td class="termin droppable nochKeinTermin">7</td>
        <td class="terminRightBorder droppable nochKeinTermin">8</td>
    </tr>
</table>    
<br />
<br />
When I click the red cell it shows column "2" which is correct.
<br />
When I click the blue cell it should also show column "2" but it shows column "1".
```

and in jquery

```
$('td.nochKeinTermin').click(function(){
  var myCol = $(this).closest("td").html();
  var myRow = $(this).closest("tr").index();
  alert('Row: ' + myRow + ', Column: ' + myCol);
});
```

Comment: Ok thanks but this is just a work around when the table cells contain the numbers (1, 2, 3)

Comment: How to get the right column index when the cells are empty? http://jsfiddle.net/rwurzer/no4sefyu/2/

Comment: It's alright. I just hide the figure inside the cells (font-size:0px). Not very nice but it works for me.