# build sortable table from multiple ajax request PART II

Tags: php, jquery, html

i have some question here.

i have a php script that request data from other web service.

but i need to request many data which i need to queue them all and wait one by one.

so i request that data using jquery (async), but the problem is, all data sorted by their loaded sequence.

so how to request them all by async, sorted them by price(for example like column 6) and serve them as table..

thank you for answer and suggestion..

so here's my code.

this is my table container

```
<table id="searchh" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="10px" cellspacing="1px">
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

i request new `tr` via this

```
$.get(request, function( my_var1 ) {
        $('#searchh>tbody>tr:last').after(my_var1);
        });
```

content of `request` is like this

```
<tr>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>random number</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: can you get data at once instead of calling each time ??

Comment: i call them one by one since every record can has different load time

Comment: i didnt get `different load time`??

Comment: this is how it works,
example: 1 have 5 row with time load (3sc, 5sc, 1sc, 9sc, 2sc) for every row
if i request it once then i need to wait 20sc to have it load all,..
so i request them async,.
so the fastest time load row will appear first and i can get all 5 row just in 9sc.
sorry, about my bad english

Comment: ok... before calling do u no the order?? if so, call in that order only

Comment: i call them manually, one by one,..
so the first row must be the fastest one, not the bigest one,..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91897/discussion-between-niranjan-n-raju-and-ryan-arief).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer for your question,

in ajax after fetching data from server,trigger a click on `price`,
 like this,

```
$.get(request, function( my_var1 ) {
    $('#searchh>tbody>tr:last').after(my_var1);
    $("th#price").trigger( "click" );
});
```

dont forget to give id for th which has price, and `trigger should be called after you fetch all records`

Rest can be found in the [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gFzCk/2938/) here.

Hope it helps you.

resource from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160277/jquery-table-sort)

Comment: works good sir, thanks,..
but when i enter table inside my tr, it only sort my tr without tble inside it

Comment: trigger should me made on `th`, or provide a fiddle so that i can edit and help you.

Comment: you have one more table inside a table??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91899/discussion-between-niranjan-n-raju-and-ryan-arief).