# Sorting tr elements alphabetically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to sort `tr` but I've no luck by far.

Here is my `tr` structure.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="./BlueSky-TexasHealthResources/index.php" >Blue Sky-Texas</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="./BlueSky-TexasHealthResources/view.php">View Data</a>
    </td>
    <td id="blue_sky_texas">

    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id = 'bj'>
        <a href="./BountyJobs/index.php" >Bounty Jobs</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="./BountyJobs/view.php">View Data</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here is Javascript that I've tried by far.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $tr = $("tr");

$(document).ready(function () {
    var alphabeticallyOrderedTr = $tr.sort(function (a, b) {
        return $(a).find("a:first").text().toLowerCase().localeCompare($(b).find("a:first").text().toLowerCase());           
    });
    $("#container").html(alphabeticallyOrderedTr);
});
</script>
```

And below is the image for table (unsorted using above code :( ).
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery table sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160277/jquery-table-sort)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.sort()` is `Array.prototyope` method, not jQuery method. Try adding [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get) or [`.toArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/toArray/) before `.sort(function(){})` called ; e.g., `$tr.get().sort(`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $tr = $("tr");
  var alphabeticallyOrderedTr = $tr.get().sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).find("a:first").text().toLowerCase().localeCompare($(b).find("a:first").text().toLowerCase());
  });
  $("#container").append(alphabeticallyOrderedTr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="container">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a>Y Jobs</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a>Z Jobs</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id='bj'>
      <a href="./BountyJobs/index.php">Bounty Jobs</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="./BountyJobs/view.php">View Data</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a>X Jobs</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="./BlueSky-TexasHealthResources/index.php">Blue Sky-Texas</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="./BlueSky-TexasHealthResources/view.php">View Data</a>
    </td>
    <td id="blue_sky_texas">

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```