# Sorting a table that has <input>'s in the table data

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, plugins

I am using the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160277/jquery-table-sort) to sort my table. The code and plugin work great but some of my `<td>`'s have `<input>` tags with values corresponding to the user who's row it is. The sorting system will not work will the `<input>`'s value. Been working on this for awhile and figured I'd ask on here how to get the sorting to look at the input values too.

```
var table = $('#user-table');
$('.sort-id, .sort-username, .sort-lastname, .sort-firstname')
.wrapInner('<span title="sort this column"/>')
.each(function(){

    var th = $(this),
        thIndex = th.index(),
        inverse = false;

    th.click(function(){

        table.find('td').filter(function(){

            return $(this).index() === thIndex;

        }).sortElements(function(a, b){

            if( $.text([a]) == $.text([b]) )
                return 0;

            return $.text([a]) > $.text([b]) ?
                inverse ? -1 : 1
                : inverse ? 1 : -1;

        }, function(){

            // parentNode is the element we want to move
            return this.parentNode;

        });

        inverse = !inverse;

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this......

```
table.find('td input').filter(function()
```

and then get the values of the inputs like so

```
return $(a).attr('value') > $(b).attr('value')
```

and also change the parent to move

```
return this.parentNode.parentNode;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gFzCk/2998/

Comment: any chance for it to work for both inputs and plain tds?

Comment: in sortElements you just need to check if input or td and get the value according to the element.