# how to sort a column in a html table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have data displaying in an html table. I need to sort only one column
    https://jsfiddle.net/5a3j7ek1/

```
<iframe width="100%" height="300" src="//jsfiddle.net/5a3j7ek1/embedded/"  allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

how do i get the data from the structure number column and sort it?

Comment: You want to sort based off of what? The first column? Second? Are you wanting to use javascript to do this?

Comment: could you try to take a look to  [jQuery table sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160277/jquery-table-sort)

Answer (score 0):

Including tablesorter: http://tablesorter.com/docs/

HTML

```
 <table id="mytable" class="tablesorter">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>First Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td originalid="pivot__R1" class="p-dim-member" fidx="1" val="109">
            <div class="wrapper">
              <div class="p-head-content"><span>109</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>data3</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td originalid="pivot__R4" class="p-dim-member" fidx="1" val="11" style="height: 24px;">
            <div class="wrapper">
              <div class="p-head-content"><span>11</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>data5</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

JS:

```
$("#mytable").tablesorter();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5a3j7ek1/1/