# jQuery header sort in table made with div

Tags: jquery, sorting, jquery-plugins

I want to order table content clicking in the header of each columns.

This question was already made here [jQuery table header sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202252/jquery-table-header-sort) but the jquery plugin pointed out there (which actually is very good) works with table html tags. Is there a plugin out there to make exactly the same if  my table is written with divs.

Html example:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="col1">col1</div>
        <div class="col2">col2</div>
        <div class="col3">col3</div>        
    </div>    
    <div class="item">
        <div class="col1">content11</div>
        <div class="col2">content21</div>
        <div class="col3">content31</div>            
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="col1">content12</div>
        <div class="col2">content22</div>
        <div class="col3">content32</div>            
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you table is written in divs it isn't a table :)

Comment: Can you show an example of your html?

Comment: This is an terrible workaround, but... as a last resort you can make a hidden table with the same data, use the plugin to sort it, and then read + deposit the contents of the sorted table into your divs.  Yeah... sketchy I know.

Comment: @Chazbot: Sketchy at best. Inventive non the less :)

Comment: @peehaa: yes, it is not an html table, but at least looks like one :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can't get around writing the code yourself, the basic process to write this yourself would be as follows.  Might sound like a pain, but if your data is clean jQuery's selectors will really help you out here:

- Iterate through your data grid assigning 2 classes to each cell (one unique to the row, and one unique to the column).  A nested loop would do it, along with jQuery's `.addClass()`. You'll need these later as jQuery selectors. I would include the table headers in this iteration, but assign them the class of 'label'.
- Make each of your table headers `$(".label")` clickable.
- When a `$(.label)` is clicked, get the classname of the row or column, and select all cells that match. Iterate over this array (html elements), and create a 2nd array of the data each cell contains (via `.html()`, perhaps). Sort this array, then use it to re-fill your original array of elements, and you're good.

Might sound complex, but jQuery was really built for this sort of thing. Good Luck.