# table sort when table header is clicked

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i am using asp table and repeater.i need to sort the data when the table header is clicked. how can i sort the table data when i click the table header? can anyone help me please
my html code is as follows

`<div class="blue">
         <table id="mytable" data-sortable class="table table-hover table-striped">
         <thead>
          <tr>
            <th id="sl">Code</th>
            <th id="nm">Name</th>
            <th data-sortable="false">Edit</th>
            <th data-sortable="false">Delete</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
      <tbody>
<asp:Repeater runat="server" id="rptArea" >
          <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
<td> <strong> <%# Eval("strAreaCode")%></strong></td>
<td> <%# Eval("strAreaName")%></td>
<td> 
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs"><a href="AreaMaster.aspx?strAreaCode=<%#   Eval("strAreaCode")%>&Action=Edit" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Edit"> <i class="fa fa-edit" style="font-size:24px;color:red;"></i> </a> 
  </div> 
</td> 
<td>
 <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs"> 
<a href="AreaMaster.aspx?strAreaCode=<%# Eval("strAreaCode")%>&Action=Delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete"> <i class="fa fa-trash" style="font-size:24px;color:green;"> </i> </a> 
</div> </td> 
</tr> 
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</tbody>
</table>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by two ways.

**Client Side sorting**

1. use a [jQuery plugin](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) like sortable or [this one](https://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/), [so post having many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683712/html-table-sort)

**Server Side sorting**

1. Make your table header as linked button/ button

`<asp:LinkButton ID="sl" runat="server" CommandName="Code" CssClass="hrefclass">Code</asp:LinkButton>`

2. Handle the click event on server
3. Sort the datasource e.g. data table and rebind it to repeater control

Refer [this](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2014/10/csharp-sorting-columns-in-repeater-control-in-aspnet.html) for example

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/1434/) using bootstrap, this might help you

```
<table data-toggle="table"
>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="fruit" data-sortable="true">Item</th>
        <th data-field="date"  data-sortable="true" data-sort-name="_date_data" data-sorter="monthSorter">Date</th>
        <th data-field="type"  data-sortable="true">Type</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr><td>Pear  </td><td data-month="1">January</td> <td>Fruit</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Carrot</td><td data-month="3">March</td>   <td>Vegetable</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Apple </td><td data-month="2">February</td><td>Fruit</td></tr>
</tbody>
```

```
<script>
function monthSorter(a, b) {
    if (a.month < b.month) return -1;
    if (a.month > b.month) return 1;
    return 0;
}
</script>
```