# Making table sortable in Dash html Table component

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have a table in my app with Dash, but I made it using the html components and not with the DataTable of Dash. The app is quite big and already configured, so I would like to avoid rewriting it. In html there is the `<table class="sortable">` which makes the table sortable. However, when I construct the table with dash, where should I write this attribute? Here is my table code:

```
def generate_table(dataframe, max_rows=1000):
    return html.Table([
        html.Thead(
            html.Tr([html.Th(col) for col in dataframe.columns])
        ),
        html.Tbody([
            html.Tr([
                html.Td(dataframe.iloc[i][col]) for col in dataframe.columns
            ]) for i in range(min(len(dataframe), max_rows))
        ])
    ], style={
        'margin-right': 'auto',
        'margin-left': 'auto'
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a class to a Dash component, simply pass it via the `className` keyword,

```
... style={'margin-right': 'auto', 'margin-left': 'auto'}, className="sortable")
```

The class itself won't make the table sortable though, you'll need to load an [appropriate JavaScript library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55730907/2428887). In Dash, scrips are [usually loaded on app initialization](https://dash.plotly.com/external-resources). However, for this type of library to work, it must be loaded *after* the table has been render, which can be achived using [this library](https://pypi.org/project/dash-defer-js-import/). Here is a small example,

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import dash_defer_js_import as dji


def generate_table(dataframe, max_rows=1000):
    return html.Table([
        html.Thead(
            html.Tr([html.Th(col) for col in dataframe.columns])
        ),
        html.Tbody([
            html.Tr([
                html.Td(dataframe.iloc[i][col]) for col in dataframe.columns
            ]) for i in range(min(len(dataframe), max_rows))
        ])
    ], style={'margin-right': 'auto', 'margin-left': 'auto'}, className="sortable")


df = pd.DataFrame({'Fruits': ["Apple", "Banana"], 'Vegetables': ["Tomato", "Cucumber"]})
app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([generate_table(df), dji.Import(src="https://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/sorttable.js")])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Comment: Should you be able to see this js script added to the html if you inspect?