# Formatting HTML tables in Julia with Dash

Tags: html-table, julia, styling, plotly-dash

I am trying to format an HTML table using Dash in Julia. Based on the third example from the [Julia Plotly page](https://dash-julia.plotly.com/getting-started), I am using the "generate_table" function:

```
function generate_table(dataframe, max_rows = size(dataframe)[1])
    html_table([
    html_thead(html_tr([html_th(col) for col in names(dataframe)])),
    html_tbody([
        html_tr([html_td(dataframe[r, c]) for c in names(dataframe)]) for r = 1:min(nrow(dataframe), max_rows)]),
    ])
end
```

and calling this function with a dataframe, cleverly called "df":

```
generate_table(df)
```

This works fine, but the resulting table is shoved against the left-hand side of the webpage.
How can I style the table to be centered on the page?

I've tried defining the `style` of the html_table using [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63793969/making-table-sortable-in-dash-html-table-component) from Python, using `style="text-align:center"` or `style=["text:align:center"] at the end of the` html_table` tag as in the following example. Since Julia no longer uses curly brackets, I've changed the curly brackets in the Python example to both parentheses and square brackets (and no brackets at all), but still have not found a solution.

```
function generate_table(dataframe, max_rows = size(dataframe)[1])
    html_table([
    html_thead(html_tr([html_th(col) for col in names(dataframe)])),
    html_tbody([
        html_tr([html_td(dataframe[r, c]) for c in names(dataframe)]) for r = 1:min(nrow(dataframe), max_rows)]),
    ], style="text-align:center")
end
```

This `generate_table` function gives me this error on the resulting page:

[image]

I've tried looking for Julia-based examples of how to style these tables, but I'm not finding much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Style arguments — like all key-value-like arguments — are passed as dictionaries.  The transliteration of a python dict like `{'text-align': 'center'}` is a [`Dict`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.Dict):

```
style = Dict("text-align"=>"center")
```

Note that you can also use [`NamedTuple`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Core.NamedTuple)s for a more succinct shorthand, but dashes aren't valid Julia identifiers so you instead use camelCase:

```
style = (textAlign="center",) # The comma is important!
```

Comment: Thank you, @MattB! This is certainly helpful. Would you happen to know how to center the table on the page, and not just the text in the columns?

Comment: Nevermind -- it turns out, the solution was this: `style = (textAlign="center", marginLeft="auto", marginRight="auto",))`