# Dash to streamlit

Tags: python, streamlit

I have found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63793969/making-table-sortable-in-dash-html-table-component) written for das to make html table sortable. I want to apply same code or the feature in streamlit but could not do it.

Would appreciate for any support on this.

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import dash_defer_js_import as dji


def generate_table(dataframe, max_rows=1000):
    return html.Table([
        html.Thead(
            html.Tr([html.Th(col) for col in dataframe.columns])
        ),
        html.Tbody([
            html.Tr([
                html.Td(dataframe.iloc[i][col]) for col in dataframe.columns
            ]) for i in range(min(len(dataframe), max_rows))
        ])
    ], style={'margin-right': 'auto', 'margin-left': 'auto'}, className="sortable")


df = pd.DataFrame({'Fruits': ["Apple", "Banana"], 'Vegetables': ["Tomato", "Cucumber"]})
app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([generate_table(df), dji.Import(src="https://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/sorttable.js")])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```